# Can the word ‘genius’ be used as an adjective?

Tags: nouns, parts-of-speech, attributive-nouns

Can the word 'genius' be used as an adjective?

For example: 'A genius plan' or 'This is a genius piece of work'?

Comment: Yes, but using *wizard* instead gets you bonus points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this noun used as an adjective?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is, yes.

This usage of 'genius' as an adjective is relatively new and would still be considered by many (including me) as slang. In that vein, the following would also be acceptable:

*my genius girlfriend*

*Your plan is genius!*

However, it would be more standard (and advised in formal settings) to use the word 'ingenious' in all of these examples, including your own, as it is an adjective.

Therefore:

*an ingenious plan*

*an ingenious piece of work*

*my ingenious girlfriend*

*Your plan is ingenious.*

As a note, I imagine that the use of 'genius' as an adjective has in fact arisen as a mistaken combination of the two words 'genius' and 'ingenious' in much the same way as the erroneous 'irregardless' has come from 'regardless' and 'irrespective'.

Also, not to be confused with *ingenuous*.

Comment: Those are not adjectival uses of *genius*. It is still a noun there.

Comment: How so?Compare "my genius girlfriend" with "my clever girlfriend". Together 'clever' and 'girlfriend' create a noun phrase, but clever is an adjective. Same is so for 'genius', though as I said, it is certainly a new application of the word. It is used this way widely, though I wouldn't use it myself outside of 'chatty' conversation.

Comment: It’s like with your *idiot girlfriend* and your *farmer girlfriend*. Those are attributive nouns, not adjectives. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: I'm unconvinced. I'd accept that it started out that way, but I think it's made the shift. I also think it's pretty bold to be throwing the word "wrong" around so certainly in this context. The phrase "that is genius!" is very common today, in a way that "that is idiot" and certainly "that is farmer" would absolutely not work. I agree that it is uncomfortable for the more pure at heart, but that doesn't mean it isn't happening. Such is language; it is happening all the time.

Comment: A minor caveat—one I have had to clarify several times on this site—I am British, and it is entirely possible that my observations are restricted to BrE usage.

Comment: Interestingly, @intuited has joked about the word "wizard" in the comments; in England, this is in fact also used as an adjective—or at least it was in perhaps the 70s/80s—"Wizard!". Again, very British, perhaps.

Comment: Very nicely sidestepped the rest of the point there, how sneaky. One might even say it was genius! I shall look for some evidence of wizard, though being mostly slang/dialectic I might struggle, if I'm honest.

Comment: You'll see a few here if you look through, 3 or 4 on first page: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20wizard%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1981,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en and also a definition here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wizard   Any of that suffice?

Comment: Hardly.  The OED attests *wizard* as both noun and verb, and the concomitant *wizarding* as a a verbal noun. However, the participial adjective *wizardizing* it marks as obsolete.

Comment: Also for your consideration: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/genius

Comment: Yes, and once again I shall remind you that I have put all of these down as slang. From this point on, if you choose to ignore the ngram references and the dictionary examples, I shall consider this exchange over, as it would be a waste of time to continue.

Comment: Well, the ones listed in the dictionary links as adjectives are adjectives, for a start. Sure you couldn't work that one out for yourself? And I would like to see your case for calling wizard a noun in "on the way back it was wizard to see the Norwegians waving to us" and "To be be kissed by Bill with that curious combination of gaiety and gravity was wizard".

Answer (score 3):

I'd just point out that "ingenious" is not the adjective form of "genius," and the meanings differ significantly.  While using "ingenious" in the above instances would make sense, try substituting the word "clever" or "inventive." That would be a good approximation of what you'd actually be saying.  When you think of the word "ingenious," think of the words engine or engineer--they have the same Latin root.  "Genius" has a different root.

Comment: Agreed, @Blake. Fortunate that it works out for these examples. (+1)