# Is the noun "points" used as an adjective in "a points victory"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, attributive-nouns

I read this recently in [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/charlemagne/2012/10/19/the-kiss-of-life-or-of-death):

> At the end of the summit, the French and European officials had
> claimed **a points victory** over the Germans by getting them to agree
> more firmly to a target date of January 1st next year to entrust the
> European Central Bank (ECB) with the ultimate authority to supervise
> the euro zone’s 6,000-odd banks.

"**Points**" is a plural, and I suppose it doesn't function as a noun in this sentence since it's following the article "**a**", so is it an adjective adorning "**victory**"?

Comment: As you see, there are (so far) two answers, and they are both right. It *is* a noun but it's used *as if it were* an adjective, so we call it something else. And by the way, your reasoning is very sound; you just didn't know the terms. +1

Comment: You could call *points* the (noun-) modifier. Though it's a noun itself, that doesn't prevent it from modifying the actual noun in the sentence, which is *victory*. With the modifier, the sentence's noun (-phrase) is *points victory*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a noun is used this way it is called an [attributive noun or noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

One big difference between attributive nouns and adjectives is that while an adjective is predicative, i.e., a *big dog* is big and is a dog, a *points victory* is not points, but rather it is a victory when using points as the determining factor.

Comment: As DavidSchwartz said, when you say a "points victory", "victory" isn't modified in any way, which is exactly how I feel. If you simply say they "claimed a victory over...", I can understand it, but when a "points" is added, I'm then confused. You can say "a overwhelming victory", because when you use an adjective to modify the word "victory", it makes sense. But in this case using a noun to modify "victory" doesn't make sense to me, and that's why I doubt if it is a modifier at all. Do you really understand what this phrase mean? If so, could you please elaborate it for me?

Comment: @zwangxian, yes, *points* tells what kind of victory was had. The winner of a points victory is declared by comparing the number of points each side has accumulated.  This may or may not align with other types of determinations.  For example after a boxing match a winner may be declared based on the number of points each boxer was awarded by the judges, but someone just watching the fight may believe that the other guy should have won based on the damage done by his punches.  A "points victory" is usually a technical victory only and and is thus not as satisfactory as an out and out victory.

Comment: But there are also non-intersective adjective/noun structures. A _heavy smoker_ is not necessarily heavy, a _good dancer_ may not be good, and a _fake diamond_ is certainly not a diamond that is fake (though there are grounds for reclassifying _fake_'s POS here). A _former pupil_ is no longer a pupil, though 'former' is of course not a noun here.

Answer (score 6):

As I've mentioned in a comment to another post, it's probably fairer to say that "adjective" ~ "noun" form ends of a spectrum rather than mutually exclusive categories.

However, on balance, reasons for saying that "points" is more "noun like" in this case would include:

- the fact that "points" is marked as plural, whereas e.g. the plural is not possible in "a yellow/*yellows victory"
- the prosodic difference between "a points victory" vs e.g. "a clear victory"
- the ungrammaticality of "*the victory was points" vs the grammaticality of "the victory was clear"
- the ungrammaticality or oddness of "*the score, points victory" vs the grammaticality of "the clear, resounding victory"
- combined with the observation that canonically "adjective-like" words go before canonically "noun-like" words, the observation that "a clear points victory" is grammatical, whereas "*a points clear victory" is not.

None of these obesrvations on its own would be a "smoking gun", but combined, they suggest that "points" is towards the "nouny" end of the spectrum in this case.

Comment: The first reason stands. / Notice the prosody in *this time, it was not a single, but a double victory*. / *An utter victory* v. **the victory was utter;* and conversely *was that victory knock-out or points?—it was points, but it was good!* / *?It was a Napoleonic, Pyrrhic victory;* and *?it was a double, clear victory* v. *it was a clear double victory.* / *A clear Pyrrhic victory* v. **a Pyrrhic clear victory*.

Comment: In short, I think it is possible to cast doubt on such reasons. The only two that I think stand beyond doubt are 1.) *points* is normally a noun, as shown in your first example; 2.) it is here used to modify a(nother) noun, which is normally the typical function of adjectives. I think those are the two most important points to consider, and based on that I think *points* cannot be near either end of the spectrum. You could argue for its being closer to one end than the other, but not a great deal. You could say it is more like an adjective in *this* sentence, because it modifies a noun *here*.

Comment: I do think you have clearly and cleverly demonstrated that *points* is not an ordinary adjective here—but, then, neither are many other words that we normally call adjectives. I personally prefer to say that a word can be *both* noun and adjective rather than that it is in a spectrum, because I think being one does not necessarily detract from being the other as well. Similarly, I feel that a participle is both verb (internally) and adjective (externally), and a girl is both woman and child (not somewhere in a spectrum). But that doesn't really matter.

Comment: I agree with much of the above. Where I believe my position differs is that I think you can usefully define a scale (in reality, a set of features) with "canonical nouniness" at one end and "canonical adjectiveness" at the other, and that in this case "points" lies quite heavily towards the "canonical nouniness" end of the scale.

Comment: It is worth bearing in mind that when we talk about "categories" like noun, verb, adjective etc, in reality what we're probably talking about is words that in the typical case share some canonical set of features. Or put another way, what we actually have is a multi-dimensional scale or spectrum between all of the categories. Or put another way, there aren't really any "categories" at all.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/dictnotes/attrib.htm) attempt to address the 'adjective, noun, or somewhere in between?' problem in their classification schema: 'While any noun may occasionally be used attributively, the label _often attributive_ is limited [in M-W] to those having broad attributive use. This label is not used when an adjective homograph (as iron or paper) is entered. And it is not used at open compounds (as health food) that may be used attributively with an inserted hyphen (as in health-food store).' ...

Comment: We return to the problem 'Who decides when the adjective homograph (I'd say intercategorial polyseme) exists as such? Neil's analysis here shows a commendable attempt to position _points_ along the N ... A continuum.

Comment: @Cerberus 'I personally prefer to say that a word can be both noun and adjective rather than that it is in a spectrum, because I think being one does not necessarily detract from being the other as well.' Do you mean 'I personally prefer to say that a word can be both noun and adjective simultaneously'? The snag with this is that it will fail inclusion tests for both POSs. Some words in some usages certainly exhibit some canonical properties of two POSs (eg his slowly _painting_ the horse fascinated me // there were pavilions _galore_ in the field).

Comment: +1 How did I miss this post before? Nice answer.

Comment: Some say that when a word appears before a noun and modifies the noun, it's an adjective. But consider *This is my ___ bag.* I could find one thousand nouns that could plausibly fill in the blank, modifying *bag*: *snack bag*, *phone bag*, *pencil bag*, *business bag*, *weekend bag*, *Grand Rapids bag*... At a guess, half of all nouns could modify *bag*. Are they all adjectives? Should we change the dictionaries? Or just admit that nouns modifying nouns is a thing: *taco bowl*, *socket wrench*, *Super Bowl ad*, *Navy ship*, *amnesty program*, *expansion pack*, *rose bed*, *garlic breath*...

Answer (score 3):

Richard Nordquist, at [About Education](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Attributive-Noun.htm), supports the belief that there are unresolved difficulties in deciding on whether some usages should be considered examples of 'adjectives' or 'attributive nouns':

> •  "Webster's New International Dictionary . . . does not call every
>   noun capable of attributive use an adjective but some like cash, land,
>   mind etc. are labelled 'n(oun) often attrib(utive).' However, the
>   distinction between words that are 'n often attrib' and words that are
>   'adj' is not precise, as the editors themselves claim . . ..
>
> Moreover, even one author may provide different explanations for
>   similar cases. Gove (1964:165), for example, considers the word *zero*
>   in *zero modification* an adjective in the light of its attributive
>   and predicative uses, despite the fact that it neither inflects for
>   degree nor admits adverbial modification. However, surprisingly
>   enough, for *macaroni salad*, apparently similar to the zero
>   modification example, he argues that there appears to be a 'strong
>   feeling' against macaroni as an adjective." (Isabel Balteiro, The
>   Directionality of Conversion in English: A Dia-synchronic Study. Peter
>   Lang AG, 2007)

I'd throw in a *plastic spoon* and a *tantalum rod*.

A deeper discussion, including the debate about whether 'gradience' should be accepted as a necessary concept when seeking to allocate POSs to words in given sentences, is given in [Pastor Gómez' Nominal Modifiers in Noun Phrase Structure: Evidence from Contemporary English.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NEX3SFVDfYUC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=adjective+attributive+noun+gradience&source=bl&ots=fKFbh-p6Jz&sig=3mGj1-L_UuDRweIKuwm0keSuqqc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UDOnVIv6J8vvavrFgJAL&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=adjective%20attributive%20noun%20gradience&f=false). I think the views of Denison he quotes are particularly important:

> Denison (2001) recognises that diachronically there is a movement of
>   some modifying nouns into the class of adjectives, and that there is
>   thus intersective gradience from noun into adjective by some nouns in
>   modifying position, such as *fun* and *key*. In the case of *fun*, for
>   example, it is used as a modifier in attributive and predicative
>   position (eg a *fun* home; that new game is *fun* [to play]). Denison
>   even cites an example with a superlative ending, *funnest*, pointing
>   out that this is 'a sign of full morphological adjectivehood'....
>
> Denison argues that there is no simple switch from the noun into the
>   adjective category, but rather a series of transitions from one
>   category into the other.'

[Of course, the pure noun *fun* still exists happily.]

Answer (score 2):

No, the noun is not used as an adjective. It's used as a noun. Sequences of nouns can act as a single noun, like "chemistry lab" or "car door".

Comment: "In grammar, a noun adjunct or attributive noun or noun premodifier is an optional noun that modifies another noun, meaning that it can be removed without changing the grammar of the sentence; [*it is a noun functioning as an adjective.*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)

Comment: I think that's a simplification to the point of being flat out incorrect. Since this is a function nouns in fact have, they are functioning as a noun when they do it. And it is nothing like what adjectives do. When you say a "points victory", "victory" isn't modified in any way. Instead, the concept of a "points victory" -- a noun in its own right, though one composed of two words -- is invoked. This is not like "green car" means "a car that is also green". A "points victory" is not "a victory that is also points".

Comment: Your argument boils down to 'it is a noun, so when it functions as an adjective that is a noun function, therfore it is functioning as a noun' - a circular argument. It is also a false premise, as 'noun' describes the function, not the word. If it names, it is a noun. If it modifies a noun, it is an adjective. *Victory* is modified by *points*. What sort of victory is it? It is a points victory, and distinct from a military victory or a political victory. What sort of car is it? It is a green car, and distinct from a red car or a blue car.

Comment: "Adjective" is in fact a recent addition to the classical 8 parts of speech. Latin grammarians simply called them nouns (they had the same inflections and agreed the same way as nouns and could be used as nouns freely, as they can in many languages). So relying on definitions of "adjective" is a losing game; they're sometimes attributive (nounlike) and sometimes predicative (verblike).

Comment: @RoaringFish: Here, it names. In the phrase "points victory" both "points" and "victory" name the thing referred to, namely a points victory. It is distinct from other victories, but it is also distinct from a blue car, or a points loss. It is nothing like a case where a noun is modified, like a "green car" where the car is modified to be green. A points victory is not a victory that is also points. "Points" works with "victory" to, together, name the specific unified thing referred to, namely a points victory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ~ "A points victory is not a victory that is also points." - If a points victory is a not points, what is it? As I understand it, a points victory is achieved by having the most points, so points is exactly what it is.

Comment: @RoaringFish: A "points victory" is not points, it is a victory. When a noun is modified, it is changed with an additional property. A "green dog" is green, it has this property it was modified to have. We can imagine a "small lab", a "medium lab", a "large lab", even a "very small lab". This modifies the lab. But a "chemistry lab" cannot be modified into a "physics lab". They name completely different things, though both are labs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ~ you keep repeating that a points victory is not points. For the second time - in what way is it not points? What is it won on, if not points? You take a lab, and modify it into a lab that has the property of being small. You take a car, and modify it into a car that has the property of being green. You take a victory, and modify it into one that has the property of being won on points.

Comment: The same way a chemistry lab is not chemistry or a Iran report is not Iran. A points victory is not points. Yes, you modify it into one that has the property of being *won* *on* *points*. That is, it is *not* points, but is actually a specific type of victory that is being named (that you can describe as "a victory won on points"). See the difference? A "green car" is green, green being an attribute the car has. A "points victory" is a thing that is not points that is being named. The victory doesn't have the attribute of points. This is nothing like the way an adjective modifies a noun.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ~ "Yes, you modify it into one that has the property of being won on points" - Correct, and a word or phrase performing the function of modifying a noun is called....?    BTW, there is no reason that a word functioning as an adjective has to describe an attribute. Learn about non-inherent adjectives here -> http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/xadjv3.htm

Comment: @RoaringFish: You can describe anything as a "modification" and thus make any word an adjective. This is just not what "modification" means when we say an adjective modifies a noun. This "modification" causes it to name a different thing. Determining what is named is what nouns do, not what adjectives do. Yes, you can describe a "points victory" as a "victory that is won by having more points". But that is nothing remotely like a "victory that is also points", which is what it would have to be if it was the kind of modification adjectives do.

Comment: I fear people aren't heeding John's point. If anything "adjective"-"noun" form ends of a spectrum. There are cases where the two poles are sometimes evident, e.g. in some languages, "adjective" vs "noun" do have more consistently different morphology (consider German) or syntax/phonology (consider French "DE jeunes [z] Africains" vs "DES jeune(s) africains"). But it's not clear at all that they're two mutually exclusive categories.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ~ "You can describe anything as "modification" and thus make any word an adjective" - that is correct, as long as it is modifying a noun. Word classes describe functions, not strings of letters or sounds, and the function of an adjective is to modify a noun. I suggest you follow the link I provided, as you still insist that adjectives only do "X that is also Y" which is simply not true. An 'old friend' could be a teenager, and a 'heavy smoker' could weigh only 40kg, but dictonaries list both old and heavy as adjectives.

Comment: @RoaringFish: The general viewpoint among linguists is quite opposite to "word classes describe functions". If word classes describe functions, what do we call the, well, classes of words and phrases that have overlapping functions? In the sentences "My dog is a Laborador. My dog is brown. My dog is in the park", the phrases "a Laborador", "brown" and  "in the park" all have the same function (predicative complement), but the first is a noun phrase, the second is an adjective phrase, and the third is a prepositional phrase. See Pullum: http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ZAA_final_proof.pdf

Comment: @sumelic: first, your examples are phrases, not words. Second, consider the numerous instances of nouns becoming verbs. In "Google is a search engine" and "I will google it" the string of letters is the same. So why is one a noun and the other a verb? It can't inhere in the string of letters because that doesn't change, so it must be because they perform different functions in the sentence: one is a noun because it is doing what nouns do, and the other is a verb because it is doing what verbs do.

Comment: @RoaringFish: Nobody is saying part of speech is based on spelling. The existence of homographs makes it obvious that that couldn't be true. The usual idea of part of speech is that it is a lexical categorization, per Geoff Pullum's title. A word's lexically-defined category determines the various ways in which that word, or phrases with that word as its head, can be used (for example, nouns or noun phrases can be subjects of verbs, or objects of verbs, or objects of prepositions).

Comment: @RoaringFish: For example, any English speaker, upon hearing a sentence like "The zackle is kulfing", will be able to conclude that the word "zackle" can also be used in contexts like "I saw the zackle kulfing" or "The zackle in the forest is kulfing" or "The yellow zackle is kulfing". In contrast, it's not possible to conclude from this data that "I will zackle it" is grammatical. It might be, but it's not determined.

Comment: @sumelic: to be accurate, I did say "Word classes describe functions, *not strings of letters or sounds*". The point being that you cannot point to a string such a 'google' and declare it a noun. Whether it is a noun or not depends on how it functions in the sentence matrix - is it doing what nouns do? - and your Pullum link agrees with me on this. Take a look at page 257, 3rd paragraph, the sentence beginning "the right definitions of nouns..." Isn't that a description of words  'functioning as nouns', just as I said, by  being objects/subjects/plurals etc?

Comment: @RoaringFish: Part of speech is based on how a word can function in general, not on how it functions in the context of a specific sentence or phrase.

Comment: Moving on to 'zackle', how do English speakers conclude that it is a noun? From the way it functions in the sentence. It is a noun because it is the subject of the sentence, has a preceding article, etc. That is a different function to zackle in "I will zackle it" where the function leads to the conclusion that it is a verb. Whether it is grammatical or not depends on externalities.

Comment: "Google is a search engine" ~ in that specific sentence 'google' is a noun. "I will google it" ~ in that specific sentence 'google' is a verb. Of course it depends on the specific sentence the word is in - or are you saying that we can simple declare that a particular string is a noun and is 'wrong' if it ever  functions as anything else - that is what 'function in general' implies.