# Compound noun or adjective + noun?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

*Substitute teacher* is an adjective and a noun, where substitute is an adjective as defined in the dictionary. However, what about *replacement teacher*? Replacement is defined as a noun in the dictionary. Does that make *replacement teacher* a compound noun or is *replacement* in this situation an adjective nevertheless?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Call it whatever you like. Knowing the name tells you nothing unless you know all about what the names actually mean. And in this case there is no real difference in English.

Comment: Nouns can act as adjectives in this kind of construction in English. They're called ***noun adjuncts*** when they do. The distinction between a noun modified by an adjective or noun adjunct and a simple compound noun is blurry at best.

Comment: Doesn't the stress pattern change in English between compound nouns and adjective-noun combinations? (Consider the difference in pronunciation between *White House* and *white house*.) I believe I pronounce *substitute teacher* as a compound noun, but *replacement teacher* as an modifier-noun combination, but it's hard to tell with phrases as multisyllabic as these.

Comment: A noun can function as an adjective. That's a widely used facility in English. Please also visit [ell.se] and see the questions-answers there.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute is indeed a noun:

> [substitute](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/substitute) n.: One that takes the place of another; a replacement.

As @EdwinAshworth points out, it is also an [adjective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/substitute%5Badjective%5D):

> being such in appearance only and made with or manufactured from usually cheaper materials; synonym: artificial - MW

Regardless of the label, it functions as an adjective in the pair *substitute teacher*.

*Replacement* is a noun, and means substitute as well. This is a case of a  noun acting as an adjective. *Replacement teacher* is exactly the same as *substitute teacher.* Does it retain its essential property as a noun when used as an adjective?

According to [Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/compound_nouns.htm), most compound nouns are made up of two nouns or an adjective and a noun. For example:

> Noun + Noun: Bath tub, witchcraft, seaman, wall-paper
>   Adjective + Noun: Hardware, highway, full moon, whiteboard

Other sites define it similarly, or restrict it to two nouns. [Edufind](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/nouns4.php) Is even looser, stating it's a *noun plus another word* and gives examples:

noun + noun: bedroom
noun + verb: rainfall, haircut
noun + adverb: hanger-on, passer-by
verb + noun: washing machine, driving licence
verb + adverb: lookout, drawback
adjective + noun: greenhouse, software
adjective + verb: dry-cleaning, public speaking
adverb + noun: onlooker, bystander
adverb + verb: output, upturn, input

But this we do know: technically, Adj. + Noun => compound noun. And, noun + noun => compound noun. So, I think that is what the comments above are about. Labels may complicate things. There are lots of labels for the same thing. You do not need to know all the labels to learn, write, and speak English.

A substitute teacher is the same as a replacement teacher. Until the replacement becomes permanent. In this economy, both are a blessing.

Edited to reflect information in comment.

Comment: Hi, medica. I've just come across this thread via another. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/substitute[adjective]) also gives _substitute_ as an **adjective**: substitute     adjective 1
_being such in appearance only and made with or manufactured from usually cheaper materials_ <substitute wools. That a noun may also be used attributively is accepted by almost all authorities (eg football manager, peanut butter). The picture gets really messy when one tries to classify all premodifiers as being one or the other. An article has been written analysing _steel_ in  'steel bridge'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Thanks for pointing that out. I'll amend my answer to reflect this. Not an excuse, but sometimes my earlier answers surprise me. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It's my Achilles' heel of spelling. :) Thanks.

Comment: Come back!! We need more ladies on EL&U :)

Comment: Sorry, I've not made it clear enough. Many would say that 'In the string _football boots_ , _football_ is functioning as a noun (pre-modification of head nouns being one of the properties nouns can display). For the best treatment I can find on ELU, see the discussion, and especially Neil Coffey's answer, to [Is this noun used as an adjective?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective/87611#87611)