# Word-formation process - which one?

Tags: word-formation

I would like to ask if anyone knows what word-formation process takes place when we join two separate words (for instance 360 + flip) and create a word '360 flip' written separately, but used as a single noun (He did a beautiful 360 flip trick). I know that *compounding* means the joining of two separate words to produce a single form, but this is different because in my example we do not have one single form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound noun or adjective + noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146828/compound-noun-or-adjective-noun)

Comment: Why so you say that _360 flip_ is not "one single form"? Because there is a space character? That's just spelling, not language. If it works like a single word, it **is** a single word, nomatter how its spelled. Spelling is arbitrary and doesn't represent the real language; only a few parts of it.

Comment: Note that it is *use*, not spelling which defines such collocations as "single forms". Spelling  usually flops around for a while before settling on a standard; see, for instance, ‹base ball› and ‹base-ball› before ‹baseball› was universally adopted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now everything is clear to me.

Comment: Rather than saying **360 flip** is two words *added* together, you could say it's a shortening of **360° flip** (i.e. - *subtracting* from the original spoken form **three-hundred and sixty *degree* flip**).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, compound nouns can be spelled as one word (toothpaste), two words (vacuum cleaner) or with a hyphen (radio-controlled). Often there is more than one option. Therefore your example is in my opinion also a compound noun.

Comment: 'radio-controlled' is a compound adjective.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. You are right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had to compose an answer, so I'll just give myself the honours. As all the commentators have said before, it is indeed *compounding*, spelling has nothing to do with it being treated as one lexical item. But if you pronounce it **three sixty flip**, that is also a *shortening* of **three-hundred-sixty degrees flip**.