# In the word “quantum mechanics”, is quantum a noun or an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

In the phrases containing the word *quantum*, like quantum mechanics, quantum information, quantum computation, quantum field theory,etc. is *quantum* a noun or an adjective? I mean, is it really *mechanics /field theory/etc. of quantum* or a mechanics/field theory/etc that has some property (like the word *classical* in classical mechanics)?

The word *quantum* itself is a noun, but sometimes like in the phrase *quantum information* it seems to be an adjective (like *classical* information), and sometimes like in quantum mechanics it's ambiguous.

(motivation:I have problem translating it to other languages)

Comment: Why do you want to translate it? Is there some language which does not already have a word or phrase meaning *"quantum mechanics"*? You certainly do not need to preserve the parts of speech in translation. In French, it's *la mécanique quantique*, and *quantique* is clearly an adjective. In German, it's *die Quantenmechanik*, which is a noun (I believe composed of two nouns, and meaning *"the mechanics of quanta"*).

Comment: Nouns are routinely used adjectivally. There are several discussion of this on the site, such as [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective).

Comment: @bib: In English, yes. But not necessarily in other languages.

Comment: @PeterShor And this site is about English

Comment: @PeterShor Actually there are some phrases, and I want to choose the most correct one.

Comment: "Most correct" in your language may not be "most correct" in English. The "correct" translation of *quantum mechanics* into French is *la mécanique des quanta*. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+mécanique+des+quanta%2C+la+mécanique+quantique&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20mécanique%20des%20quanta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20mécanique%20quantique%3B%2Cc0) shows that this was in use for a few years after the word *die Quantenmechanik* was coined, but has since been completely supplanted by *la mécanique quantique*.

Answer (score 5):

Etymologically, "quantum" is the neuter singular form of the Latin word meaning "how much." As used in English in physics, it's a noun. It refers to one indivisible unit, e.g., the photon is the quantum of light, and *e* is the quantum of electric charge. The plural is "quanta," which is the neuter plural form, used in English as a plural noun.

In phrases like "quantum mechanics," "quantum state," and "quantum information," it's a noun being used to modify a noun, like "elephant gun" or "sandwich shop." The antonym is "classical." (Sometimes people use "classical" in contradistinction to "relativistic" as well, but that's incorrect. Special relativity and general relativity are classical theories.)

Although phrases like "quantum mechanics" are completely set in stone by tradition, there are alternatives such as "quantal" and "quantum mechanical." E.g., people do often write "quantum mechanical behavior" rather than "quantum behavior." "Quantum theory" refers to the abstract theoretical framework (e.g., it states that wavefunctions are complex numbers), while "quantum mechanical theory" implies the nonclassical version of a particular theory, e.g., the liquid drop model of the nucleus is classical, but there is also a quantum mechanical theory of nuclear physics.

Comment: So, form your answer, my impression is that both are correct, more or less.

Answer (score 4):

Etymologically  *"quantum mechanics"* was the English translation of the German word *"die Quantenmechanik",* which was coined by a group of physicists at the University of Göttingen, including Max Born, Werner Heisenberg, and Wolfgang Pauli. [(See Wikipedia.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_quantum_mechanics) In the German, *"Quanten"* (the plural of *"Quant"*) is a noun meaning *"quanta"*, and *"Quantenmechanik"* would have meant *"the mechanics of quanta"*. So when the term *"quantum mechanics"* was introduced, the word *"quantum"* was a noun.

Comment: When they finally crack computing based on ***quanta***, it'll be interesting to see if anyone comes up with a way to do the same with [***qualia***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/qualia). (*"To infinity and **beyond**!"* :)

Comment: How about quantum field theory or computation? *Quantum* here is certainly an adjectives, right?

Comment: It certainly seems like an adjective in *"quantum computation",* and I believe it is one in *"quantum field theory"* as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

It is a noun being used to describe another noun. In "quantum field thory" both "quantum" and "field" are being used as noun adjuncts. See the link. In some other languages an adjectival form would be required.