# Parts of speech and functions: "Bob made a book collector happy the other day"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, parts-of-speech, functions

Having been bamboozled by various questions and answers on this site, I'd like to know what are the parts of speech (POS) and grammatical functions of the words and phrases in the following sentence:

> 1. *Bob made a book collector happy the other day.*

Here I am particular interested in the status of the following items:

- book
- happy
- the other day

But I also need the parts of speech and functions of all the individual words in the sentence. By functions I mean *subject, complement* and the like. I would also like to know the evidence for the assignments to specific functions and parts of speech.

The reason for asking this question is because the status of the three items listed above may be thought contentious by some people. For example, it might be argued by some that *book* is an adjective, whilst others will say it is a noun. Similarly, *the other day* some will argue is an adverb. Whether *adverb* here should be regarded as a function or part of speech in such analyses seems unclear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19924/discussion-on-question-by-araucaria-parts-of-speech-and-functions-bob-made-a-b).

Comment: Since it is closed, I'll answer briefly here. "book" is a noun but functioning here as an adjective, just like "pet" in "pet cat" or "grammar" in "grammar book". In general nouns can be made to function that way. "happy" is clearly an adjective, and a complement to the verb "made". The syntax is "made X Y" where "X" is a noun and "Y" is either an adjective or a noun phrase, such as in "made him happy" or "made him one happy person". "the other day" is an adverbial phrase modifying the entire "Bob made a book collector happy". In general noun phrases denoting time can be used adverbially.

Comment: @user21820 I heartily approve of your answer! And agree with almost all of it. Thank you! If this question gets reopened, maybe you could post it  there!! Just to clarify one of the most important points, you're saying *the other day* is a noun phrase, right? :-) Because I definitely would agree!

Comment: @Araucaria: Yes; it is a definite noun phrase. What else can it be? =)

Comment: @user21820 Well exactly, but some people round here seem to think it's an adverb! Even though it's three words ...

Comment: @Araucaria: You can also pose your questions to the Stanford parser at http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp. I find it to be a rather accurate parser for standard (perfect) English.

Answer (score 14):

Although this question almost feels like three questions in one, I will try to answer all three parts — and the general question concerning the whole sentence as well.

---

### book

In the noun phrase *book collector*, the noun *book* is a ***noun adjunct***, it is used *attributively*. A common way of expressing this is to say that *book* is used as an *adjective*, but this does not mean that the noun *is* an adjective. It just plays a similar role.

Looking up ***attributive noun***, we find, for example, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/dictnotes/attrib.htm) telling us about the label *attributive* used in dictionaries:

> The italicized label often attributive placed after the functional label noun indicates that the noun is often used as an adjective equivalent in attributive position before another noun:
>   <sup>1</sup>bot·tle . . . *noun, often attributive*
>   busi·ness . . . *noun, often attributive*
>   Examples of the attributive use of these nouns are *bottle opener* and *business ethics*.

Nouns used in this way are often said to be *adjectives* or *act as an adjective*. However, they are not. Adjectives do things that these nouns do not:

> A great collector => a greater collector — *We can form comparatives from adjectives.*
>   A book collector => *a booker collector — *Nouns do not like it when we do that.*
>
> A great collector => the collector is great — *We can use a copula followed by an adjective.*
>   A book collector => *the collector is book — *Nouns do not like it when we do that!*

In the answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective) some more arguments are listed.

---

### happy

This is an ***adjective***. It modifies the noun (phrase) *book collector*. As we can see in this explanation from [perfect English grammar](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/let-and-make.html) about using *make* and *let*, this is a very simple construction where we use subject + make + object + adjective to mean “cause the object to be the adjective”:

> We can also use subject + make + object + adjective. This means 'cause the object to be the adjective' (the adjective can be good or bad):
>   • Her story made me really happy.
>   • The traffic jam made us late.
>
> ---

### the other day

This is not an *adverb*, but a *noun phrase* that is used as an ***time adverbial***.

The [British Council](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/adverbials-time) teaches us about adverbials of time:

> We use adverbials of time to say:
>
> • when something happened
>   • for how long
>   • how often (frequency)
>
> We often use a **noun phrase** as a time adverbial
>
> ---

### the whole sentence

> Bob made a book collector happy the other day.

**Bob** — a noun functioning as the subject in the sentence.
**made** — a verb, functioning as the main verb describing the action that the subject executes.
**a book collector** — a noun phrase, functioning as the object of the sentence.
**happy** — an adjective, modifying the object of the sentence.
**the other day** — a noun phrase functioning as a time adverbial modifying the verb.

The noun phrases can be further taken apart as follows:

**a** — indefinite article
**book** — noun adjunct, or attributively used noun, modifying *collector*
**collector** — noun, head of this noun phrase

**the** — definite article
**other** — adjective modifying *day*
**day** — noun, head of this noun phrase

Comment: +1 Nice answer:) As you'll see, I'm about to put a bounty on this. I was wondering if you felt like giving any simple bits of evidence to show why *book* is a noun, for example?

Comment: @Araucaria: evidence as to why _book_ is a noun? I could try to conjugate it in the sentence to show it is not a verb, I could try to form a superlative to show it is not an adjective... But I am not sure what _evidence_ you are looking for? A simple refutation of it being an adjective is easy enough, if that is what you mean :)

Comment: Superlative/comparative would be good! Could modify it I suppose? (i.e. does this require an adj or an adv, etc). :)

Comment: I added two arguments and a link :) Any more ideas for additions are welcome, I'll have a look at them when I get home :)

Comment: @oerkelens I may add some later, but I don't want to kill off any competition just yet ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: You are quoting selectively, I think: " The simple answer is “Yes.” A better answer is “Well sure, sorta.” But the best is answer is “What’s an adverb?” And thereon hangs a much longer tale." So I think you might read _simple_ in _simple answer_ as: "The obvious, simplified answer, that keeps things nice and simple without getting into details", but it is immediately followed up by "but there is a better answer"...

Comment: @oerkelens Agreed, however, that 'better' answer implies that **next Tuesday** is kind of an adverb. It doesn't say that *next Tuesday* can't be an adverb because it's two words. The commenter was implying that the status of noun phrase adjuncts isn't disputed when they're more than one word! This is just not the case. The commenter has talked abbout multi-word adverbs or adverby things in other posts too, as I recall. It's a valid concern of the question here.

Comment: The concern is certainly valid - not only about supposed multi-word adverbs, but certainly also the nouns that are suddenly adjectives. I myself have been reprimanded for calling a noun an adjective, and I fully agree that I deserved the reprimand. (And I subsequently became very fond of the words _attributive_ and _attributively_ :) )

Comment: If 'the other day' may be atomised (I'd prefer to regard it as a unitary time adverbial), 'other' is not an adjective but a determiner. It references 'day' within a (time) framework rather than describing attributes (this _fine_ day).

Comment: I mostly work with lower-level ELLS for whom this stuff never comes up. For them, I'd just say "book collector" is a compound noun and leave it at that. But for my own education: the *pecan* of "pecan tree" would be a noun adjunct/attributive noun?

Comment: @miltonaut: yes, _pecan_ is a _noun adjunct_ or _attributive noun_ in _pecan tree_.

Comment: @oerkelens: Thanks! I've been using *adjectival noun* for all these years, but apparently that's not the proper term any longer nor has been for some time.

Comment: @Araucaria - Not here any more: Why can't we say that _the other day_ is an adverb phrase modifying _happy_?

Comment: @user405662 Well, it's not an adverb phrase because none of the words in it's an adverb. More importantly, it's a noun phrase. But if your question is whether we could say that *the other day* is modifying *happy*, the answer is that in theory it could be, although the meaning would be slightly different. The most natural reading of the sentence is probably that whatever Bob did to make the book collector happy was done the other day. It is, of course, possible though that the imaginary speaker intends to say that the result was the collector was happy the other day. So, yes. Kinda!

Comment: I have been taught that in the sentence _They rested at noon_, _at noon_ is an adverb phrase modifying the verb _rested_ (answering the question _rested when?_). Here too neither of the words in it is an adverb. Or have I been taught wrong then? @Araucaria - Not here any more.

Comment: @user405662 Well, that's kind of very 19th Century ;). In modern grammars, the good ones anyway, there's a clear line between word and phrase categories on the one hand and grammatical relations on the other. "Adverb phrase" in that bad, old type of grammar is skewing the line between the function of the phrase and the type of phrase it is (how it is built). It's like the difference between 'Noun Phrase' and 'Subject'. When that 19th century grammar say 'adverb phrase' in that kind of sentence, it means 'modifier of a verb phrase'. It says nothing about what kind of Phrase it is!

Comment: @user405662 The problem is described, entertainingly, here: [Lexical Categorisation in English Dictionaries and  Traditional Grammars](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ZAA_final_proof.pdf) Enjoy!

Comment: @Araucaria— Thanks a lot! And Pullum I highly adore. Am sure gonna enjoy it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Parts of speech are categories, their members sharing various properties. One of these properties is the functions that the members **can** perform. These functions are relations, and each should be capable of coming before *of*. For example, in *book collector*, *book* is a dependent (more specifically an attributive modifier) **of** *office*. It generally makes no sense to say that something is a noun **of** or verb **of**.

If we look at families. Man and woman are categories (like parts of speech). You can see a man or woman outside of a family situation and generally still put them in the right category based on various properties such as facial hair, breasts, size, voice, etc. One of the properties of men is that they **can** function as 'husband of', 'brother of', 'parent of'. Women can be distinguished from men partly in their inability to function as 'husband of' or 'brother of', but both men and women can function as 'parent of'.

Back to words, the members of the category of English nouns share a range of properties, not just the relations into which they enter. They (typically) inflect for number, and many name concrete objects. Adjectives have other properties, like inflecting for grade (tall, taller, tallest). Number and gradability are distinguishing characteristics, but functioning as 'attributive modifier of' nouns is a shared characteristic. Only when *book* takes on more characteristics of adjectives such as becoming gradable (*booker*, *bookest*; like *fun*--traditionally a noun--being inflected *funner* and *funnest*) would we say that it actually now belongs (also) to that new category.

Here, as always, *happy* is an adjective (it inflects for grade: *happier*, *happiest*), but its function is not attributive modifier but rather the predicative complement of *make*. Here, we could say also *she made the book collector president*, and *president* would similarly be the predicative complement of make. Finally, *the other day* is a noun phrase (it's headed by a noun & can function as a subject of a verb). It's not an adverb (it can't be modified by *very*, it doesn't inflect with *-ly*). It is an adjunct of *make*.

There are many more properties of adjectives, nouns, etc, but it would be too much to discuss here. Suffice it to say you need to look at more than simply the relations something enters into.

Comment: +1 for a very good analogy. I disagree with your definition of what puts a word in the _adverb_ class (which is of course the messy bastard child of word classes to begin with), and you seem to have neglected/forgotten to comment on the syntactic function of _the other day_, unless you consider ‘adjunct’ on its own a syntactic function (I’d disagree with that, too—it’s a category, not a function; I’d also consider _the other day_ an adjunct of the sentence as a whole, rather than of _make_). Other than that, I pretty much agree with everything you’ve said here.

Comment: It's not really a definition, just some typical characteristics, but yes, adverb is messy.

Comment: Yes, I think it's an 'adjunct of' the verb. Adjunct is the relationship it has with the verb. You can't look at a word or phrase standing on its own and say, "that's an adjunct". And yes, there's a good argument to say it's an adjunct of the clause.

Comment: Note that I didn’t say _adjunct_ is a word class category—it’s a category/group of functions. The trouble with _adjunct_ is that it’s not a single thing and not a single function, just like, say, _argument_ isn’t. There are different types of adjuncts that function in fundamentally different ways and are _adjuncts of_ fundamentally different things. An attributive adjective or noun is also (in some views, at least) a subtype of adjuncts, for example. _The other day_ here I would label a(n adverbial) temporal clausal adjunct (because to me it modifies the clause, not the verb).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Brett  Doesn't that just make it a general function. For example, *complement* is a function, but we can be more specific and say *Direct Object* or *locative complement* or *complement of a preposition* etc? [Also *adjunct* is used slightly differently by H&P, or for example Bas Aarts, whilst passing].

Comment: Well, see, I would also say that _complement_ isn’t actually a function itself, but a superset of certain functions. But maybe that’s just me being overly programmer-like and structuralist. Sure, all adjuncts have _some_ things in common; but the five adjuncts in “Yesterday, I really made that book collector happy about his newest purchase all right” function in such different ways that I just think that especially with _adjunct_, the blanket term is almost as useless as the blanket ‘adverb’ category.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood @JanusBahsJacquet. Yes, it's a higher-level function name: dependent > adjunct > etc. You could get more specific, but I think this level of generality is appropriate to the question.

Comment: @Araucaria Really, apart from this stuff about adjunct functions, I would basically just be repeating Brett’s answer. He said almost exactly what I would have said, using (probably) about a third of the space I would have ended up with.

Answer (score 2):

Book collector is a noun+noun compound.

Happy is an adjective.

The other day​ is a noun phrase.

Comment: +1 Quite so :)! Any ideas about the *functions*? (Subject, Object etc?)

Answer (score 1):

### Abstract

The example expression can be redistributed in the following structure:

[Subject][Verb][Object][Modifiers]

Each phrase serving one of the above mentioned purpose is further sub-divided in to individual parts of speech.

Result
[image: Structure of the Expression]

### Description

Structure of an expression can be deduced by understanding the following:

- Meaning
- Grammar
- Style/Idiomatic usage

---

[image: Relations and Parts of Speech]

I'll tackle this by identifying the right questions and proposing precise answers.
Expression: Bob made a book collector happy the other day.

1. What is going on here?
   --> (Someone) made (Someone) happy.
   Verb = made
2. What did they make? - (That is how was verb applied)
   --> happy - a state
   A state would be an abstract Noun.

---

3. Who made (Someone) happy? - We are looking for the Subject, the entity that did the activity in this case
   --> Bob
   Bob is a subject. Bob is also a (Proper) noun.
4. Who was made happy? - We are looking for the Object, the entity for which the task was done
   --> a book collector
   'a book Collector' is an object.

'A' is the indefinite article. An indefinite article points to nonspecific objects, things, or persons that are not distinguished from the other members of a class. Essentially, articles are Adjectives as they point to a noun.

In addition, 'book collector' is a compound of: Book + Collector.
What does a 'book collector' mean?
Someone who collects books.
Breaking this further down, a 'book collector' is a type of collector who collects books.
As 'book' provides the information on the type of the noun 'collector', 'book' is an adjective.
'Collector' is a noun.

To read more on Noun Phrases and Compound Nouns, refer to: [Compound Nouns](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/compnounterm.htm)

To delve deeper in to the nuances, 'book collector' is a Noun phrase or Noun-equivalent.
Source:[Chicago Manual of Style - Noun-equivalents and substantives](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec010.html)

---

5. When did this happen?
   The other day
   We get the information about when the action took place. Therefore, 'The other day' acts an adverb.

Looking in to the terms individually:
'The' acts as the 'definite article to 'other day'and acts as an adjective.
     More on the topic: [Purdue University OWL: Using Articles](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)
'day' is the time when this occured. It is a Noun.
'other' tells us about the day. It is an Adjective.

More on compound adverbs here: [Chicago Manual of Style - Phrasal and compound adverbs](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec158.html)

---

PS: Thank you for the rep points. I've successfully added a detailed image and links to cite. Thanks for the workout. Please review and suggest updates.
Edit: *Formatting, Structuring, Adding information

Comment: Thank you my upvote fairy! Now, I'll improve this answer.

Comment: Nice diagrams! And a proper go at explaining the functions! Thanks. But I'm not sure about *happy*. I don't think that this is a modifier of *made*, I think it's a *complement* of the verb. The word *happy* is often a modifier in noun phrases, but it is usually a complement when it is a phrase in the verb structure. Here it describes the object, so we could say it is a *predicative* complement. But nice diagrams etc :-) (I don't think I can upvote it yet, because of the 'happy' issue!

Comment: Also, is there any reason why *book* is an adjective here? You don't seem to give a reason ... You talk about its function, describing/modifying *collector* but not specifically about the part of speech.

Comment: @Araucaria What an insight! Let me start by admitting that I am not certain of the answers that I'll suggest. Let me try, nevertheless. A [Verb Complement is an object to the verb] (http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm). By calling it an Adverb, I am adhering to the definition-  _An adverb is a word that qualifies, limits, describes, or modifies a verb..._(http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec153.html). Now, _book_ - Considering the Compound Noun, the Part of speech that _book_ plays must be relevant to the phrase and must not be judged standalone. Views?

Comment: *"the Part of speech that book plays must be relevant to the phrase and must not be judged standalone"* - actually, that's one reason why I asked the question. Really the role that a word/phrase plays relevant to the larger phrase it is in is its *function*, not its part of speech. So *modifier*, *complement* and so forth are descriptions of the function. But parts of speech can be thought of as being independent of a particular role they are playing (we need to be careful though, because there are many homophones out there!). So, although *book* is a modifier of the word *collector* it ...

Comment: ... isn't really an adjective. Both nouns and adjectives can be modifiers of other nouns. We can do tests to find out, for example, we can have a *rare book* collector. Here we are using an adjective to modify the word *book*. If *book* was an adjective we would normally have to use an adverb, because adjectives can't usually modify other adjectives. But we can see that a *rarely book* collector doesn't work here ... Does that help? (You could look at Brett's answer - it's not as thorough as yours, but it has some good explanations) :-)

Comment: This just keeps getting better! On the record, Parts of Speech are not my forte. But, here is to another take. _rare book collector_. _rare_ modifies _books_. rarely_ is not idiomatic. IMO _rare_ is an adjective. To solve this, consider that _rare books_ is a compound modifier in itself. A simile can be drawn with [rare] [http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rare]  in "rare roast beef". Of course, all these inferences are drawn on the assumption that Form (PoS) follows Function. :)

Comment: Personally, _rare book collector_ presents an ambiguity - Is the book rare or is the book collector rare? In the previous comment, we have chosen what was convenient to us. It may not be accurate. Therefore, I discourage such a use. (That's what studying for GMAT does to you :'( ) Keep me posted. :)