# Adjectives versus Noun Adjuncts

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

What determines whether something is a "noun adjunct" or just a garden-variety adjective?  Does it matter in any meaningful way?

Here is my hypothesis, but I can't find any authoritative source to back it up. I'm hoping someone here can weigh in more definitively.

1. Classification of noun adjuncts is based *subjectively* on whether the word is in "common usage" as a noun.  "Book" and "chicken" are commonly nouns and would be considered noun adjuncts in "book collector" and "chicken soup"; "yellow", not so much.
2. Noun adjuncts may share some common qualities that differentiate them from other adjectives (like not being able to be inflected into superlative forms... one can't be a "book-est collector").  But they are still fundamentally *adjectives* and may even appear in the dictionary as such if the adjectival usage is common enough.

What I've found so far...

Wikipedia defines a "[noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)" as:

> an optional noun that modifies another noun; it is a noun functioning as an adjective.

But English words are not decreed to be nouns or adjectives by some higher authority.  So it seems strange that one can prescriptively conclude that something "is a noun" in the first place, let alone extrapolate that it "is a noun functioning as an adjective".

The wiki article cites "chicken soup" as an example of a noun adjunct, but at least [one dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chicken?s=t) gives a definition for "chicken" as:

> adj. (of food) containing, made from, or having the flavor of chicken

So it seems that there are some differing points of view on how to categorize these words.

This question was spawned from some discussion in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217760/what-is-the-difference-between-a-part-of-speech-and-a-function/217788?noredirect=1#comment464249_217788), [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218058/parts-of-speech-and-functions-bob-made-a-book-collector-happy-the-other-day) and [this other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb).

Comment: Whether a word is a noun is based on syntactic data. For example: is the word modifiable by adjectives or adverbs; is the word gradable (***big, bigger, biggest*** versus ***chicken, chickener, chickenest***). Dictionaries are no authorities on parts of speech. The grammars published by the same publishers are.

Comment: The OED calls these "nouns used attributively" like how a baby cat is a kitten; that uses the noun *baby* attributively.

Comment: Are you asking whether "it's a noun or an adjunct"? Nouns can be adjuncts and adjectives can be adjuncts. Maybe you're asking whether it's a noun or an adjective? Or maybe you're confused between the part of speech and the function?

Comment: @Araucaria. What do you mean by 'The grammars published by the same publishers are [authorities on parts of speech]'? There are differences in analyses in many areas. 'Intransitive prepositions' are not accepted by all grammarians, for instance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, indeed. But no grammar or syntax publications abide by the parts of speech attributed to words by dictionaries. There may be contentious cases, but no serious grammar published by OUP or CUP (apart from ELL pubs) say that, for example, *umbrella* in *umbrella stand* is an adjective. And no grammar papers published for grammarians or syntacticians in reputable academic journals would refer to it as such. Basic grammars even ones as old as *CGEL* 1985 distinguish between part of speech and function :)

Comment: ***""noun adjunct"*** <== Is that a Part-Of-Speech (category?) or is it a syntactic function? -- cc. @Araucaria

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think the stuff in that other question is pretty much what I'm looking for, but it's so buried amidst discussions that I hesitate to support this as a "duplicate".  Also it lacks any references cited.

Comment: @Araucaria - If there is a grammar that answers this question then that is exactly the sort of answer I'm looking for.  As it stands, I lack access to such a reference and the general reference meta list doesn't seem to have one.  I have only the definition of adjective = "a word that modifies a noun", which every schoolchild knows.  "Chicken" in "chicken soup" appears to fit that definition, hence my confusion.  I am not a linguist - that's why I'm asking here!

Comment: I've added an answer there, with a couple of references. It seems rather crazy to say that 'plastic' in 'plastic spoon' is an adjective (though the adjective appeared well before the noun, albeit not with the 'made from ...' sense) while 'steel' in 'steel knife' is a noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My spoon is plasticker than your spoon. :)

Comment: 'If there is a grammar that answers this question then that is exactly the sort of answer I'm looking for.' But then you'll think the next grammar you read which offers different analyses is 'wrong'. I'd nearly agree with Araucaria: 'umbrella' remains nearer the noun side of the noun-adjective continuum when used as a premodifier. But that's just one example. I'm usually happiest with [Collins'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iron) treatment. eg for _iron_: **iron** 1b noun (as modifier): _iron railings_ /.../ adj
11. very hard, immovable, or implacable: _iron determination_

Comment: @tchrist Explains why you keep bending the rules :)

Comment: If you look at the monograph 'Nominal Modifiers in Noun Phrase Structure: Evidence from Contemporary English'
 [Pastor Gómez, Iria] now linked to in the earlier thread, you'll find nearly 200 pages of analysis essentially saying 'The situation is fluid, if rather viscous; analysis of some cases is difficult, and there is scope for disagreement'.

Answer (score 4):

> But they are still fundamentally adjectives

Here's where I disagree with the rest of your description, that I otherwise think is correct.

If such a word is "fundamentally" anything (I'll come back to that "if"), it's fundamentally a noun: We think of it as a noun in the abstract. We can't inflect it like like an adjective *because it isn't one* (though other adjectives may not be able ). They are being used as adjectives, but take them away from that use and their adjectival quality is lost again.

> and may even appear in the dictionary as such if the adjectival usage is common enough.

But then it has developed an adjective sense. Or rather, it developed such a sense, and *then* was recorded as such in the dictionary. Or rather, some lexicographer decided that it had developed such a sense and then recorded it; I'm not convinced the entry you link to was justified; "chicken hot soup" would still be wrong if chicken were accepted as an adjective for the material, but it would be less wrong. I suppose it depends in part in whether we consider "the soup is chicken" to be a contraction of "the soup is chicken soup" or not.

> But English words are not decreed to be nouns or adjectives by some higher authority.

So there are no nouns at all?

> So it seems strange that one can prescriptively conclude that something "is a noun" in the first place, let alone extrapolate that it "is a noun functioning as an adjective".

Who said anything about prescriptively concluding something "is a noun"?

Now one can prescriptively do so (you can't stop me!) and indeed everyone does; everyone prescriptively decides what they themselves will or will not write. If you decide you are prepared to write "the wall is kitchen" or that you are not, you're being prescriptive.

But we don't need to consider that either. Descriptively you can either observe that people do not generally say "the wall is kitchen" of a kitchen wall, and so it is not an adjective, or you can argue that they might, and so it is an adjective.

I said I'd come back to the "if" of "if such a word is 'fundamentally' anything", and it's because I don't think *fundamentally* makes sense for things like parts of speech. Parts of speech, especially the traditional parts of speech, are useful classifications. Just how useful is something linguists might debate, as they might also debate just what those parts of speech actually are and e.g. whether determiners are a type of quantifier or separate, and so on.

There are senses in English that can act as a name of a thing or set of things and we call them *nouns*. They can also be used to modify other nouns they precede, and we call that use *noun adjuncts*. There are other senses that modify nouns that way and also predicatively and with adverbs further modifying them, and we call them *adjectives*.

And this is useful up to a point, but I don't think there's anything *fundamental* about any of it.

There remain qualities that nouns have, even if used as modifiers, that adjectives do not, and therefore the concept of *noun* and *adjective* remain usefully separate.

Comment: I agree with a lot of what you have, but I'm still shaky on the idea that this is 'fundamentally' a noun. (I may have used the wrong word there.)  "Home" is a word that it seems have equally-weighted adjectival, adverbial, noun(al?) and verbal uses.  How does one call it 'fundamentally' anything in the abstract?  Now in a *given instance* one can say it's acting one way or the other, but by what criteria would we argue that one use is more basic than another?

Comment: Darn it. I did say I was going to come back to "fundamentally", and then I never did. One minute...

Comment: @Lynn Some would say that those are four different words. You're asking for 'the answer' when the experts don't even agree on basics.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure that's really correct. Whether the experts agree or not is a question of numbers, not whether there's one paper kicking around somewhere that says one thing or another. "The professionals" are not in disagreement here! (Actually aren't the professionals 1970's anti-crime unit?)

Comment: @Araucaria If you troubled to read the article I linked to in a recent answer to the previous version of this question, you'd see that one analyst even claims that _zero_ in _zero modification_ and _macaroni_ in _macaroni salad_ should be labelled 'adjective' and 'attributive noun' respectively. I can't be bothered searching for the 'Are "intercategorial polysemes" actually different words?' article I once came across. I seem to remember Pullum saying something like 'English Grammar needs a complete overhaul' a few years back.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually, I read a bit of it :) But even though things are tougher when it gets down to some individual words, the principles involved are pretty stable generally. I can understand the data that might have driven that writer to mistake the determiner in the first example with an adjective: *absolutely  zero modification*, methinks ...

Comment: ... Pullum doesn't believe in inter-categorial indeterminacy, for what it's worth. Not much probably;) You might be interested in [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=13r59BPMYqYC&dq=Syntactic+Gradience:+The+Nature+of+Grammatical+Indeterminacy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_uOnVMvaOMu2UabXg7AL&redir_esc=y) by Aarts. Denison (whom you cited in the other post) and Aarts also worked on this, which is a very [interesting read](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/fuzzy-grammar-9780199262571?cc=gb&lang=en&). Very slightlyl less gripping when it forms the basis of one of your MA modules, though!

Comment: @Araucaria It's so long since I looked at ICD (most of the hits for 'gradience' in an on-site search seem to be my posts) that I can only dimly remember Aart's conclusions. Does 'The situation is fluid, if rather viscous; analysis of some cases is difficult, and there is scope for disagreement' come close?

Answer (score 0):

Can the word in question be modified with an enhancer like *too* or *very*? Then it's an adjective. Otherwise it's an attributive modifier. (The assumption is we're asking if it's an adjective proper or a noun used attributively.)

In [theFreeDictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/adjective) an adjective is:

> The part of speech that modifies a noun or other substantive by limiting, qualifying, or specifying and distinguished in English morphologically by one of several suffixes, such as -able, -ous, -er, and -est, or syntactically by position directly preceding a noun or nominal phrase.

but generally people understand it as:

> a word imputing a characteristic to a noun or pronoun

[Grammar-Quizzes.com](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj_nounmodifiers.html#grammar) indicates two descriptions, depending on the audience:

### Traditional and ESL (English for Speakers of other Languages) description:

> It's a "noun as adjective".

Arguably, in the definition of adjective in the sense of applying a characteristic to a noun or pronoun, a *file* cabinet uses the noun *file* to apply a characteristic to another noun (*cabinet*) and can be considered to be a noun used as an adjective.

### Linguistic Description:

> Current linguistic analysis describes the examples above as "nouns used as attributive modifiers". That is to say, a "noun" cannot be an "adjective" (a grammatical class) but it can be a "modifier" (a grammatical function). Because it occurs before the head noun, it is called a "pre-head modifier".  (Huddleston 4.2.2-3, 5 §14.2)
>   "Attributive nouns fail to qualify as adjectives by virtue of the grading and adverbial dependents criteria.  They don't take very or too or the analytic comparative marker more as modifier."  — Nouns as Attributive Modifiers (Huddleston 16.2.4.1)
>   A  fresh cheese cake is delicious.
>   Both fresh (adj) and cheese (n) function as modifiers to the noun cake.  The noun phrase (NP) "A fresh cheese cake" functions as the subject of the clause.
>
> Many common ideas in English are expressed by noun + noun compounds. The first noun is singular and no article is included. The second noun may be plural and may include an article (if it is a count noun) a horse race /  some horse races.
>   The first noun modifies or describes the second noun:
>   (1) the first noun classifies the second noun: (tells which kind)
>   milk chocolate (a kind of chocolate)  / chocolate milk ( a kind of milk)
>   a horse race (a kind of race) / a race horse (a kind of horse)
>   (2) the second noun is the subject of the first noun: ("for")
>   a shoe shop  (a shop that sells shoes; a shop for shoes)
>   a tooth brush (a brush that cleans teeth; a brush for teeth)
>   (3) the second noun is a container for the first noun:
>   a coffee can / cup
>   a soap dish / box
>   (4) first noun indicates the material of the second noun:
>   a gold ring / a silver ring
>   a paper flower / a silk flower
>   (Swan 385-6)
>   Ambiguous pairs occur:  a baby doctor (a young  doctor, a kind of doctor); a baby store (a store that sells babies, a store for baby goods)

In Linguistic terms, there is no ability to make a *noun* too noun, very noun, more noun-er, less noun-er, noun-able, or noun-ous, therefore it's never not a noun. The noun can be used attributively but is still considered a noun, even as its function differs from its part of speech.

Comment: 'Can the word be modified with too or very? Then it's an adjective. Otherwise it's an attributive modifier.' So 'dead' in 'dead cat' is ... This 'rule' does not distinguish between attributive nouns; and classifying, absolute, and extreme adjectives. Yes, that's a super-comma.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the cat was too dead for Frankenstein's latest experiment ;)

Comment: @Jon Hanna It must have been a very unique occasion.

Comment: It was very dead. Or mostly dead.

Comment: I am puzzled why someone hasn't produced the definition of "noun adjunct" that will decide the case. Could it possibly be because it is not a term based on actual grammar, but perhaps invented by a textbook author or publisher? Any term must have tests that distinguish whether a given constituent has this property or not; otherwise it's handwaving.

Comment: @John Lawler One of the 'tests' Gove seems to think valid is popular opinion: 'Gove (1964:165), for example, considers the word _zero_ in _zero modification_ an adjective in the light of its attributive and predicative uses, despite the fact that it neither inflects for degree nor admits adverbial modification. However, surprisingly enough, for _macaroni salad_, apparently similar to the _zero modification_ example, he argues that there appears to be a 'strong feeling' against _macaroni_ as an adjective.' (see linked thread above). Who decides on the tests?

Comment: @JohnLawler You just said the magic word *constituent*, which is otherwise missing from all this discussion. Words don’t matter; constituents do. It’s entire constituents that one says modify nouns or verbs or whatever; a prepositional phrase or indeed an entire clause can just as easily modify a noun or verb as a single word can, and all this needs to be regarded in that light.

Comment: The material you've quoted does not support your comment. You imply that *adjective* and *modifier* are equivalent terms. As is clear from the material you've cited, *adjective* and *noun* are parts of speech whereas *modifier* is a function. This is clear from the Huddleston you've quoted: ***That is to say, a "noun" cannot be an "adjective" (a grammatical class) but it can be a "modifier" (a grammatical function)***