# How is "drag" an adjective in "drag show"?

Tags: adjectives

[*The New Oxford American Dictionary*](https://archive.org/details/newoxfordamerica0000unse/page/515/mode/2up) defines one sense of drag to be:

> Clothing more conventionally worn by the opposite sex, esp. women's clothes worn by a man: *a fashion show, complete with men **in drag*** | [as adj.] *a live drag show*

Now that second bit saying that it is an adjective raises my eyebrows a bit, because that example doesn't look like an adjective to me.  I parse that as

```
a     live  drag show
det.  adj.  noun compound
```

And I feel this interpretation is vindicated if we contrast sentences like

> The show will be so extravagant.

with

> *The show will be so drag.

Here I replaced an adjective (extravagant) describing a "show" (the same noun in the sentence provided by the dictionary) with "drag" and got a sentence that seems to me to be ungrammatical.  If "drag" were being used as an adjective in the example sentence then it should be separable from the noun it modifies, and it seems to not be.  And this evidence is completely congruent with a noun compound understanding of the phrase.

Now to be a little less naïve, I do definitely see how one could think that drag is an adjective in the sentence. It is a word right before a noun that it modifies, which is basically how adjectives work most the time. And I could definitely see it being a pragmatic choice on the part of the dictionary to cater towards a simpler more common understanding. However the issue I see with this is that English allows noun compounding with basically all nouns. And the NOAD does not list every noun this way. So there must be *something* special about the word it is trying to tell me, but I don't know what it is.

So my questions here are: What's going wrong?  Have I misread the dictionary?  What is the dictionary trying to tell me.

Comment: The show will be **a** drag. [boring]. a drag show = a show with drag queens, but both those are different terms: drag show is a compound noun, and something that is **a drag** is a slang noun that means boring.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure what you are getting at.  The show will be a drag uses a different sense of the word, and is still a noun.

Comment: "The show will be so drag". would not normally be grammatical. That is what I am getting at. In drag show, it is not that drag is an adjective per se. It is a noun that functions adjectivally. Like: beauty queen or drag race. You wouldn't say: She is so beauty, would you?

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I marked the sentence as ungrammatical, so I definitely agree that it is.  And I think beauty is a fine analogy since it is also a noun.

Comment: Drag in expressions  such as: drag queen or drag party is a noun adjunct that works as an adjective, but it is not an adjective like red, good or ugly.

Comment: ***noun adjunct:*** 
a noun that occurs before and modifies another noun, as toy in toy store or tour in tour group. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/noun-adjunct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this noun used as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective)

Comment: @user66974 That’s a bit like saying a female doctor is working as a man because a majority of doctors are men! It also implies that that’s the only job a man can do!

Comment: Not all adjectives are the same. There are categories such as ungradable and absolute adjectives whose members can't be used in a lot of ways most adjectives can. If you said "so unique" or "more unique" you'd get a lot of grammarians jumping down your throat, but nobody would dispute that "unique" is an adjective. "Drag" isn't in the same class as unique, but it's definitely a word that can fulfil some of the roles of common adjectives like "red" or "happy" but not all of the roles.

Comment: Related: [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218157](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218157).

Comment: Much here depends on how one interprets ***as*** in the dictionary's use of *as adj.*. The OP has interpreted that to imply that the word **is** an adjective when so used, but perhaps the authors meant to say only that in such constructions it is **used as** an adjective, while remaining a noun.

Answer (score 2):

What the dictionary is telling you is that the word "drag" is most commonly used as an *noun adjunct*: a noun used if it were an adjective.

While "drag" is a noun in its own right, it is most commonly seen as a modifier to other nouns, particularly as "drag act", "drag artist" or "drag show".

The use of "drag" as a noun in its own right is so uncommon in everyday English that most native speakers would be confused if you said something like "this box contains some drag".

Comment: Doesn't the parenthetical remark in this answer sweep under the carpet what the question is really about? The OP seems to be puzzled precisely by the fact that the dictionary characterises the word in such contexts as an adjective, rather than a noun adjunct.

Comment: @jsw29 Perhaps.  But until I started reading English Language & Usage, I had never even heard of a "noun adjunct" - I always consider them as nouns used as adjectives.

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason *so drag* seems weird is that the *so X* construct normally needs a comparable adjective; dragger (more drag) and draggest (most drag) don't really work. It's either a drag show or it isn't.

As a native English speaker, I find the categorization of phases into *either* adjective+noun *or* compound noun to be quite unsatisfactory, as many phrases have aspects of both.

There seems to be a very small list of phrases where "drag" appears before another noun, with the whole phrase denoting "cross-dressing" (in fact off the top of my head I can only think of two in common use: *drag show* & *drag queen*), which would point towards these functioning more as idiomatic set phrases rather than a generalizable construct, and that argues against it being analysed as an adjective.

However the real test of an adjective is orthogonality: if you throw novel phrases including "drag" at an average native speaker, will they correctly infer "somehow involving cross dressing" for at least some of them:

- drag boots
- drag chains
- drag clothes
- drag crossbow
- drag fair
- drag hair
- drag in
- drag king
- drag line
- drag makeup
- drag marks
- drag match
- drag net
- drag off
- drag on
- drag out
- drag race
- drag strip
- drag trap
- drag venturi
- drag weed

As always, context and experience are everything. People involved with drag shows are going to have a different set of defaults from people who don't. And a drag trap set in the bush has a very different connotation from a drag trap run by a police vice squad.

Answer (score -3):

In "a live drag show", both "live" and "drag" modify "show", and both are therefore adjectives.
The show in question is a show exhibiting people dressed in drag, or a "drag show". Same as if you were to say "a fashion show" -- a show exhibiting fashions; or "a car show" -- a show exhibiting cars.

Now you could also say, "a live car show", to distinguish this particular "car show" from a video car show.  But "car" still modifies "show", and distinguishes it from a "dog show", "a boat show", "an arts & crafts show", etc.   Same with "drag".