# A weird case : "The kitchen’s window" vs "The kitchen window"

Tags: grammar, nouns, modifiers

I just came across this article ([noun modifiers](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/noun-modifiers)), and I'm surprised that these two nouns mean different things:

> The kitchen’s window
>
> The kitchen window

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The%20kitchen%20window%2CThe%20kitchen%E2%80%99s%20window&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThe%20kitchen%20window%3B%2Cc0) shows zero usage of the first one even though it's very common .

[image: Ngram]

Here are some articles using the first one ( The kitchen’s window ):

[The New York Times Making a New House Look Old](http://www.nytimes.com/slideshow/2012/05/18/greathomesanddestinations/18iht-redutch18-slideshow/s/18iht-redutch18-slideshow-slide-BOLP.html)

> **The kitchen’s window** and door combination has an arch similar to that
> of the brick-in arch elsewhere in the facade.

[One biotech gasps for breath](https://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/27582/title/One-biotech-gasps-for-breath/)

> [...] and an assortment of sweets soon cover a long table by **the**
> **kitchen's window** .

How come?
Thanks.

**Update :**

Thanks to @Lawrence, I've noticed that there is an Ngram apostrophe issue, and that's why it shows **zero usage** of **kitchen's window** . To workaround this issue, I used a **wildcard** and here is the result of [the kitchen * window](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20kitchen%20*%20window&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthe%20kitchen%20%2A%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20kitchen%20door%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20kitchen%20%27s%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20kitchen%20bay%20window%3B%2Cc0)
( Please, click on search lots of books to see the result ):

[image]

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+village+church%2Cthe+village%27s+church&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20village%20church%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20village%20%27s%20church%3B%2Cc0) shows zero usage of 'the village's church' compared to 'the village church'.

Comment: That's weird ??

Comment: @NigelJ : That means the second is may be wrong .

Comment: Wake up, @CryptoBird It doesn't say that they mean different things. It implies that the genitive "the village's church" is wrong, which it is.

Comment: 'the village store' 'the village post office' 'the village pond' 'the village idiot' 'the village green' 'the village hall' - the idiomatic form is reliable.

Comment: @NigelJ: ha ha 'the village idiot', I'm dying .

Comment: @NigelJ: Please, do you have any resources about this ? I really wanna learn about this topic , or just give me a hint to look it up on google. I would really appreciate it .

Comment: The kitchen's window is a generic phrase (equal to the living-room's window), while the 'kitchen window' is idiomatic. I think that's probably why the NGram doesn't show the generic form. It will show "kitchen's" and "window" separately, instead.

Comment: The Ngram issue may be simply an algorithmic quirk relating to the treatment of quote marks. If you click through to "the kitchen window" (below the graph), then add the apostrophe manually, the search returns [many results](https://www.google.com.au/search?lr=lang_en&dcr=0&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=nemjWorBOMez8QWHo4uADg&q=%22the+kitchen%27s+window%22&oq=%22the+kitchen%27s+window%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3081.3182.0.3453.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.sTip6NVRGfE).

Comment: Entering *the kitchen's window* on its own directly into [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+kitchen%27s+window&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20kitchen%20%27s%20window%3B%2Cc0) also returns a non-zero number of results. (Note: clicking on the link returns an empty result at first, but then clicking immediately on the blue "search lots of books" button returns a non-empty result. That's weird.)

Comment: @Lawrence : I don't think so, cause in computer programming, when it comes to quotes and apostrophes , programmers treat that carefully .

Comment: @CryptoBird Google "Ngram and apostrophes" for the treatment of apostrophes in Ngram. The issue goes deeper than a programming bug. In any case, as my comments above demonstrate, it isn't completely accurate to assert that "the kitchen's window" shows zero usage in Ngram - sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @Lawrence : I think you're right, the issue goes deeper than a programming bug .

Comment: @Lawrence : Please, check out the new update .

Comment: @CryptoBird Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, in the source sentence:

> The kitchen’s window and door combination has an arch similar to that
>   of the brick-in arch elsewhere in the facade.

**The possessive "kitchen's" does not modify "window", but rather "window and door combination".**  If one did use "kitchen" in this context the reader might well be led down the garden path to concluding that the reference was to a door/window combo similar to that that might be used in a kitchen (even though, in this case you could be talking about a bedroom).

And in the second source sentence:

> [...] and an assortment of sweets soon cover a long table by the
>   kitchen's window .

What's being described is the layout of the kitchen.  Thus a specific window is being referred to, and window is not so much a feature of the kitchen but rather a **"landmark"**.

**As with most things English, the rules are mushy, but the non-possessive use of "kitchen" to modify "window" implies a window of the type used in a kitchen, while the possessive implies a window which is "owned" by the kitchen.**

There is plenty of room for both forms to be used, depending on context.

Comment: I might have written: "The window and door combination *in* the kitchen has an arch..." Using the apostrophe actually speeds things up, but is it indispensable?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm sure you might have written it a number of different ways, but you didn't write it, and the usage is idiomatic.

Comment: What if the noun was table? In the 2nd sentence, would you say "... by the kitchen's table"? or just "kitchen table"? Interesting question. Food for thought (pun intended) :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - There's plenty of room for wiggling here.  Particularly with "kitchen table" there are associations and implications far beyond a mere piece of furniture.  Using the possessive conveys the sense that a piece of furniture is being discussed, rather than the place where the family has breakfast.

Answer (score 4):

They only vary slightly.

The village church: The church which is located in the village.

The village's church: The church which belongs to the village.

In the first sentence it's used a bit like "the town drunk" or "city hall" where it functions more like an adjective than a noun.

Comment: No they don't. The genitive "the village's church" is wrong! Simple as that.

Comment: @BillJ - How so??

Comment: The "village church" is not mentioned in the actual question though. So could you please direct your focus on "kitchen/kitchen's window" and the examples cited by the OP

Comment: @Mari-LouA -  Reread more carefully.  "kitchen's window" isn't cited either, in the NYT example.

Comment: @HotLicks what are you talking about? The NYT article does mention the "kitchen's window" and the "kitchen's eating area" (further along) My comment was addressed to Patrick.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Not if you parse it correctly.  It's "kitchen's (window and door combination)".  You can't just take "kitchen's window" and attempt to analyze it in isolation.

Comment: @HotLicks yes,  you're right about window and door combination, I meant that the OP mentions "kitchen('s) window" (see Ngram) and in my earlier comment I mentioned the `OP's examples`. You misunderstood me. IOW I'm saying "village('s) church" does not appear once in the OP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA : village('s) church vs village church was the original question . But since some people here said that "village('s) church" is wrong, well, I've change it .

Comment: OK  apologies, it seemed that the question was originally about kitchen window. The OP  changed the example(s)...

Answer (score 0):

A kitchen does not possess things, one or more windows are *in* a kitchen, a window is a feature.  The term *kitchen* is a **[noun adjunct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218058/parts-of-speech-and-functions-bob-made-a-book-collector-happy-the-other-day/219971#219971)**, it tells us what sort of window we are talking about.  We can go further and add adjectives or other nouns:  “a *large soundproof frosted-glass kitchen window*” for example. Saying a “large soundproof frosted-glass kitchen's* window” would sound odd, and frankly very wrong.

Wikipedia has an article which supports this grammar detail

> [**Noun adjuncts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#English) **can also be strung together in a longer sequence preceding the final noun, with each added noun modifying the noun which follows it**, in effect creating a multiple-word noun adjunct which modifies the following noun (e.g. "chicken soup bowl", in which "chicken" modifies "soup" and "chicken soup" modifies "bowl"). There is no theoretical limit to the number of noun adjuncts which can be added before a noun, and very long constructions are occasionally seen, for example "Dawlish pub car park cliff plunge man rescued", in which "Dawlish", "pub", "car park", "cliff", and "plunge" are all noun adjuncts. They could each be removed successively (starting at the beginning of the sentence) without changing the grammar of the sentence. This type of construction is not uncommon in headlinese, the condensed grammar used in newspaper headlines.

However, the "possessive" apostrophe can be used with inanimate things e.g.

> [The University's mission and core values](https://www.cam.ac.uk/about-the-university/how-the-university-and-colleges-work/the-universitys-mission-and-core-values)

Here *University* is used as a metonymy, as representing the people who run the institution. We can use the "possessive" apostrophe with objects, when the thing possessed is inseparable from its owner

> 1. The **bottle's neck** is cracked
> 2. The **neck of the bottle** is cracked
> 3. The **bottleneck** is cracked

Many native speakers would opt to say the first or the third sentence but the meaning of all three is the same. Note that *bottleneck* is a compound word,  no longer made up of two words, *bottle* and *neck*; the narrow section of the bottle which makes it easier to pour, has its own proper "name".

Comment: Thank you so much for your awesome clarification, but to be honest, I have seen "kitchen's window"  in several articles, actually .
Here is an article from new york times : 
http://www.nytimes.com/slideshow/2012/05/18/greathomesanddestinations/18iht-redutch18-slideshow/s/18iht-redutch18-slideshow-slide-BOLP.html

Comment: @CryptoBird thanks, I've got a bit of spare time to search for some references. But NYT's article is actually a very good example. Why didn't you quote that sentence in your question? The NYT is quite famous for its persnickety grammar!

Comment: @CryptoBird ahh, I have focused my attention on "kitchen window"....

Comment: There is a lot of things to learn here, thanks a million .