# In structures such as 'football manager', is 'football' a modifier or a complement of the head noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, terminology, modifiers, complements

I thought I'd post this as it illustrates a problem often encountered on ELU.

> In structures such as 'football manager', is 'football' a modifier or
>   a complement of the head noun?

I've seen both terms used as if there were only one possible correct answer. However, I've come across widely differing definitions of both 'modify' and 'complement' as used in grammar. I believe that people stating baldly that this is either one or the other are assuming a grammar that they prefer, rather than giving a balanced overview.

Notice that I intend this question to explore the usage/s of the term 'modify' and of the term 'complement' in this context. There may be overlap with the question of which word-class 'football' fits into, but that decision hardly answers the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this noun used as an adjective?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not the same question really.

Comment: If we have football players, football coaches, football managers, football memorabilia, football games, etc, which don't we consider coaches, managers, memorabilia, and games "nominal complements"?

Comment: Why did this question get two downvotes? Can a downvoter explain?

Comment: @Rathony - Well, for one thing it's identical to two other pre-existing questions.  Beyond that it's apparently attempting to settle a dispute between (at least) two different schools of English syntax analysis, and there is no "authority" to resolve the difference, so the question is "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @HotLicks Well, it could be. All grammar-related questions could be primarily (any grammar book author's) opinion based. What I meant is this question is good for current and future readers. I am not sure if it is a real duplicate as Araucaria seems to agree.

Comment: @hmm I here by note that a football manager does not manage footballs. But I also note that they do manage football!

Comment: @Araucaria - Ah, but is it ***real*** football??

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, it is the ***real*** thing! Not the stuff for wimps with shoulder pads and ladies leggings and all that. ;)

Comment: @Rathony I mentioned you in my post (because of your question about *sleeping bags* the other day)

Comment: @Araucaria It's an honor. Very nice answer.

Comment: The vast majority of Anglophones wouldn't know what "a modifier or a complement of the head noun" even means, let alone care about the answer. In fact, I'll even go out on a limb and say the vast majority of Anglophones aren't interested in football (although people on, say, [sports.se] SE would be). Just sayin' :-)))

Comment: @rand al'thor But this is a site targeted at the subset of Anglophones {English linguists ... and serious English language enthusiasts}.  Not Anglophones in general. Not the football supporters (as such), who doubtless have many dedicated sites. Not the subset wanting abstruse subject-specific (eg maths) terminology. Here, 'football manager' is a vehicle rather than the topic for discussion; substitute your own example....

Comment: Which question would you expect to be a reasonable one to be addressed in a University linguistics course: "What's the word for someone who studies partial differential equations?" or "In structures such as 'football manager', is 'football' a modifier or a complement of the head noun?"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Short answer**

<sup>(Assuming that Modifiers and Complements exist ...)</sup>

It's a Complement.

Here's some evidence, which will be explained in more detail in the longer answer. Firstly, the noun *manager* inherently implies that there is something being managed. This expectation is fulfilled by the noun *football*. This shows the tight semantic relationship we expect between Heads and their Complements. This observation is backed up by the fact that the noun *manager* derives directly from the verb *manage*. The thing being managed is an argument of the verb *manage*, and therefore appears as a Complement of the verb. As with many other deverbal nouns we would analogously expect the arguments of the noun *manager* to correspondingly occur as Complements of the noun, not as Modifiers. In addition, nouns which specifically have the thematic role of *patient* in relation to the activity indicated by the Head noun would often be expected to be able to occur either as a prehead Complement or, alternatively, as part of a post-head Complement headed by the preposition *of*:

- a **football** manager
- a manager **of football**
- a **book** collector
- a collector **of books**

In addition the word *football* must occur directly before the noun *manager*—any prehead Modifiers must come before the word *football*, not after it:

- an idiot football manager
- an overweight, second division football manager
- a second division, overweight, football manager
- *a football idiot manager
- *a football second division overweight manager
- *an overweight, football, second division manager

Lastly we can observe that *football* works badly with the anaphoric proform *one* if we want it to mean *football manager*

- I need a manager.
- I need a premier league one.
- I need a talented one.
- *I need a football one. (odd if not ungrammatical)

This is because *one* is taken to stand in for the Head noun and its Complements. We cannot then try and add another Complement to it. We could, however, modify it with an attributive Modifier as  shown in the second and third examples.

### Full answer

<sub>to be completed in installments ...</sub>

**1. An admission**

First of all, I voluntarily stick my hands up and explain that many of my posts here arbitrarily—and incorrectly—refer to any prehead dependent of the noun in a noun phrase as a modifier. Mea maxima culpa. This is shoddy. The reasons for this errant behaviour are that a) it is often difficult to determine whether a prehead dependent of a noun is a modifier or a complement b) I normally don't care either way— I don't find the prehead dependents of nouns very sexy, unlike prepositions, determiners, verb phrase complementation, relative clauses and larger constructions in general c) my knowledge about the grammar in this area is not very robust d) I often can't tell, and so therefore, given a–c above, I ignore the distinction. So far, the only people who have ever noticed are the fellow posters BillJ and possibly Rathony too.

**2.0 Complements versus Modifiers**

**2.1 Complements**

OK, with that out of the way, we can have a look at what a Modifier is and what a Complement is. Well, roughly speaking, a Complement is a phrase which fills a special slot set up by another word or phrase in the sentence. So for example, the verb *TEACH* sets up a slot for the thing being taught, the Direct Object, and the people being taught, the so-called Indirect Object. These terms such as Direct Object, Indirect Object, Locative Complement and so forth are just more specific names for Complements of a verb. Prepositions take Complements too, often noun phrases which we can also sometimes describe as Predicative Complements or Objects. Adverbs can often take Complements either directly or indirectly as well. So for example, the infinitival clause *to eat in one go* fills a special slot set up by the adverb *too* in *It was too big to eat in one go*. Adjectives can take their own various sorts of Complements too; consider *on chess* in *keen on chess* or *to leave* in *keen to leave*.

So, all sort of words and phrases can set up these slots, and all sorts of words and phrases can fill them too. Sometimes Complements are obligatory and sometimes they aren't. Of course, it's nice and handy when Complements are obligatory, because it's easy to identify them. It is also, in such cases, easy to demonstrate how that word or phrase has a special relationship with the Head of the phrase. So, unfortunately, Complements are often construed as obligatory essential accompaniments to other words or phrases when we first start to learn about them. This isn't always the case. Let's revisit the verb *TEACH*:

- I teach.
- I teach English.
- I teach students.
- I teach students English.
- I teach English to students.

Here we see this verb taking no Complements, taking one Object, taking two Objects and taking an Object and  a preposition phrase Complement. These different Complements are Complements because this verb sets up a special slot for them, not because they are obligatory.

Complements, of course, have other features. For example, they are usually selected by the word they are the Complements of. These Heads will allow certain types of Complements but not others. So for example, the adjective *keen* will select preposition phrases headed by the preposition *on*, but not ones headed by the preposition *of*:

- keen on spiders
- *keen of spiders (ungrammatical)

The verb *inquire* can take interrogative clauses as Complements, but not declarative ones:

- I inquired whether the elephants had left.
- *I inquired that the elephants had left. (ungrammatical)

Complements are thought of as being more tightly integrated into the phrases they occur in than Modifiers are. Whereas Complements are often required to be adjacent to the words that license them, Modifiers can often be moved further away from the phrases they modify or appear on either side of them. So if we see both Complements and Modifiers in the same phrase, as a rule of thumb, all other things being equal, we expect the Complements to be closer to the Head word than the Modifiers:

- Put it on the shop floor on Thursday.
- *Put it on Thursday on the shop floor. (awkward if not ungrammatical)

A sentence or phrase will often sound marked, awkward or ungrammatical if this does not occur. In the sentence above the Complement *on the shop floor* will ideally come closer to the verb *put* than the Modifier *on Thursday*.

Because Complements are more tightly integrated into the phrases they occur in than Modifiers, they are often obligatorily replaced when we use a proform, whereas Modifiers may be repeated or addended to such phrases:

- *I put my beer in the fridge and Bob did so in the cupboard. (ungrammatical)
- I drank my beer in the kitchen but Bob did so in the living room.
- *I am counting on their help, but I don't want you to do so on their help. (ungrammatical)
- I am counting on their help, but I don't want you to do so.

In the first sentence *in the fridge* is a Locative Complement. As the anaphoric proform *do so* includes the Locative Complement in the second clause in that example, we cannot then add a second Locative Complement, *in the cupboard*. In the second sentence, where *in the kitchen* is a Locative Adjunct (a Modifier), we can freely add another Locative Adjunct in the second clause, *in the living room*. In the last pair we see that the sentence is grammatical if we omit the Complement *on their help* after *do so*, and ungrammatical if we repeat it.

Lastly, semantically, Complements usually have a close relationship with the words that license them. Words inherently describe semantic relations between different things. So the verb *PUT* brings to mind a putter, a thing being put, and a location. It doesn't inherently involve any idea of time. So in *Put it in the fridge tonight*, we would not expect *tonight* to be a Complement of the verb *put*, but we would expect both *it* and *in the fridge* to be Complements, which as we have seen above, they are. The thing being put and the destination of that thing are suggested by the very use of the verb *PUT*. Similarly the noun *collector* also inherently implies that there are things which are collected and someone who collects them. The noun *resignation* implies a resigner. So in *a collector of antique books*, we would expect *of antique books* to be a Complement, and we would expect *of the President* to be a Complement in *the resignation of the President*. But we would not expect *in the corner* to be a Complement in *the collector in the corner*, because the noun *collector* does not inherently imply a location.

Because of semantic factors above we also expect Heads to impose semantic, as well as syntactic, selectional restrictions on their Complements. We can annoy elephants but not tables, unless we ascribe some sort of animacy to our tables for some reason. We don't expect such tight restrictions with Modifiers. One can do almost anything *on Wednesday* and almost anything *pointlessly*. And whereas the number of possible Complements is specified by the Head both semantically and syntactically, the number of Modifiers is not.

**2.2 Modifiers**

Modifiers are never obligatory. We can characterise them as syntactically extra elements. They are usually semantically extra too, in the sense that they are not automatically implied by the words or phrases that they modify. Unlike Complements, Modifiers are usually only loosely integrated into the larger phrases they occur in. Their position is often only loosely determined:

- I play foot ball [in the park][on Fridays][with my friends]
- I play football [with my friends][on Fridays][in the park]
- I play football [on Fridays][in the park][with my friends]
- [On Fridays] I play football [with my friends] [in the park]

As shown further above unlike Complements, modifiers are not obligatorily relaced when we use proforms to refer back to a larger phrase.

We can use various forms of cycle as an analogy for phrases here: unicycles, bicycles, tricycles, tandems and so forth. If we regard the frame of the cycle as the Head of a phrase or clause, then the Complements are all the things that fit into the different slots in the frame. So the frame dictates the size and number of wheels, saddles, handlebars and so forth (some of which may be optional, for example in the case of tandems) that the frame can take. These things are all Complements. You can't put the wrong Complements on the wrong frames. For example, a unicycle frame won't usually allow handlebars in the same way that an intransitive verb won't allow a Direct Object. Also you can't fit the wrong size parts into the wrong slots. So the stem of your handlebars must fit into the frame, for example. It cannot be too big or too small. So the frame puts restrictions on what can be slotted into it. In contrast, any lights, bells, mudguards, panniers, stickers and so forth are always optional extras. They are, to extend the metaphor, Modifiers. You can't ride your unicycle without a wheel, but a light is definitely an optional extra. Notice as well, that the bicylce frame puts very few selectional restrictions on the Modifiers available. You can stick lights, bells or horns on any cycle you want to, and any number of each as well—although admittedly things might get awkward if you do decide to use very many.

Comment: This looks very good to me. I'm not going to accept until ornery folk (ie peer reviewers) have had a chance to find more serious faults than lager phrases. // Can you find an authority endorsing 'Nouns can be Modifiers or Complements. It depends on the Head noun and its relationship with the dependent, not on the word class, or on the dependent (the word preceding the Head noun). Adjectives can have both functions too.' ?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth After ironing out the typos, I'm going to add some specifics on complements of nouns in particular, which will include vetted sources and a bit on different accounts too - but that my take some time. In the meantime, you might want to take a look here [CaGEL p.439-40](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/16/items/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language.pdf#page=453&zoom=auto,-242,851).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  In fact 439-443 are all pertinent for your Q. But you can see from the eg.s on 439 that nouns can be Mods and Comps and on 440 they discuss the adj *criminal* as both and compare the two interpretations that result.

Comment: This is too good an answer to be buried in time--answers all the questions I had about complements in the past week. I am compelled to leave this chatty comment, even it is just going to be cleaned up by the mods.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Okay. Just did!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thank YOU for the thoughtful argument and hard work!

Answer (score 2):

There’s a difference: a football manager is a manager who works in the field (sport) of football. Or a "manager of football", if you prefer.

But "football" does not denote a property of the person referred to as "manager" as say "talented" or "useless" would in "A talented/useless football manager", where the adjectives "talented" and "useless" are clearly modifiers. If "football" were a modifier (like an adjective), it would readily combine with "one", as "talented" does in "get me a talented one", but with "football" you get the very odd *”get me a football one".

Comment: But as usual with these tests, they are far from perfect. Unless one argues for conversion (I wish these puns would stop appearing), 'gas' is a noun in 'gas appliances'; there are over 100 000 Google hits for "to a gas one", including say  'We would like to switch to a gas one eventually', which I find quite acceptable. And when one looks at 'peripheral adjectives' such as 'mere' in 'a mere youth' ...

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth Me too. I'd say that "gas" was a modifier in "gas appliance", not a complement.

Comment: "What kind of manager is he?" ~ "A football one". I don't see a problem there. Regardless, you seem to be arguing that restricting "manager of anything" to "manager of football" is not a modification, which is a little odd to put it mildly...

Comment: @Roaring Fish That may be becoming more acceptable, but there are distinct differences amongst specific couplings. 'What sort of a cake is it?' _'A chocolate one.' // 'What sort of a chair is that?' _*'A deck one.' There are considerations about how near a compound the coupling is, and how adjectival the first word has become. But these don't directly address the usages of 'modifier' and 'complement'.

Comment: Please be aware that the downvote is not mine. This is useful.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ~ to be an adjective, the football manager would have to have some 'footbally' properties. An angry manager would have the property of anger. A tall manager the property of tallness. A football manager does not have the property of 'football', so it is not adjectival and hence cannot be a complement. The only modification is restrictive.

Comment: @Roaring Fish But a gas appliance doesn't "have the property of 'gas' ", which would argue for non-adjectivalness. And yet we also speak of an electrical appliance. Adjectives may show a looser 'associated with' relation.

Comment: It does indeed argue against 'gas' being an adjective, which is precisely why I have never said it is one...  You are being too prescriptive, thinking that everything that modifies a noun has to be an adjective, because grammar books say that is what adjectives do. That is wrong. Nouns can also modify other nouns.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nouns can be Modifiers or Complements. It depends on the Head noun and its relationship with the dependent, not on the word class, or on the dependent (the word preceding the Head noun). Adjectives can have both functions too. So in *a legal move* the adjective *legal* is a Modifier - but in *legal adviser* the adjective *legal* is a Complement. In *a novice driver*, the noun *novice* is a Modifier, but in  *a bus driver* the noun *bus* is a Complement

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So in *gas burner* the noun *gas* is a Complement - but in *gas appliance* it is a Modifier. (One difference, the *gas burner* burns gas - the appliance does not apply gas, as it were).

Comment: @RoaringFish If that comment is directed to me (and I don't see how it can be directed to BillJ) I find it insulting. It grossly misrepresents my views. I'm asking how **you** reconcile 'gas appliance' with 'electrical appliance'. I'm fairly sure that Araucaria is correct with 'Nouns can be Modifiers _or_ Complements. It depends on the Head noun and its relationship with the dependent, not on the word class, or on the dependent (the word preceding the Head noun). Adjectives can have both functions too.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ~ if your earlier statement that we should consider "how adjectival the first word has become" is not saying the that you think the first word is 'adjectival', then I really don't what you are arguing about. I never said anything about *gas appliance*, so I see no reason for me to reconcile anything about it. If you are saying that in *football manager*, *football* is a complement, then provide a reference that suports one element of a N+N construction being a complement of the other. I have provided three sources that say it can't be, and one supporting it being an adjunct.

Comment: In a gradience, only the end-points are true adjectives or nouns etc.

Comment: @BillJ I have mentioned you in my post ...

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the kind of question that keeps grammarians wide awake and scrabbling far into the night.  It is to be appreciated and savored.

It's a question that many dead-tree grammar books dodge and flee, leaving a trail of clearly adjectival **egg timers** and obviously adjunctive **lawn mowers** in their wake.  When pressed, authorities like Warriner and Lunsford defer to "common usage" and move on - rapidly - leaving the field to puzzled pupils and curious grammarphiles.

A sampling of this kind of "sagacity":

> In **compound nouns**, words double up to express a whole that is more than the sum of its parts.  They can be made of common nouns (*bus ride*), proper nouns (*Central Anatolia*), or both (*Galatia highlands*). They can be "open compounds" (*acid trip*) or closed ones (*daylight, slipstream*). Compounding has been common throughout the history of English, but writers and their editors don't often agree on when and whether to splice words together.
>     -Constance Hale, *Sin and Syntax*, 2013

Hale makes no mention of the possible adjectival nature of the nouns, and leaves off the concept of what commenters and answerers are calling *complements, adjuncts or determiners,* depending on their particular catechisms.

> Nouns are sometimes used as adjectives.
>
> **sofa** cushion    **hotel** lobby
>   **bread** pudding   **glass** beads
>
> When you are identifying parts of speech and you encounter a noun used as an adjective, label it an adjective.
>     -John E. Warriner, *English Grammar and Composition*, 1982

Warriner calls them all *adjectives*, period.

Conscious of the way in which nouns merge over time - think of the drifting that brought *taximeter cabriolet* eventually into *taxicab,* thence later to *taxi, cab* ... and now *Uber* - I'd like to try to strike a sensible balance.

Having ducked the question numerous times in the classroom and in small-distribution print, let me rise out of the weeds to suggest that **it depends on context.**

A **football manager** is a noun modified by an adjective if he is presented in the semantic company of other sorts of managers.

Thus the **football coach** (different continent, different title, different game...) at Blather State College is adejectivally modified in a pamphlet extolling the virtues of the school' basketball, ice hockey, baseball, lacrosse, golf, swimming and full-contact origami coaches.

If, however, I describe Meghan as our **football coach** (we are strenuous adherents of Title IX) the word "football" is an adjunct (or complement - let's not be fussy) because it identifies her rather than distinguishing her among her fellow managers.

In attempting the distinction between adjective and complement, one has to look around and see if there are any other kinds of the thing named in sight.

If the noun has the field pretty much to itself, e.g., a lawn mower rusting in a shed devoid of any other kind of "mower," we'll call "lawn" a complement.

But when we see our plucky yellow egg timer alongside our oven timer, our kitchen clock and our stopwatch, we can safely call the "egg" an adjective.

Comment: So you're defining 'adjective/modifier' as 'that which serves to distinguish type, species ... of N' and 'complement [only as used here?]/adjunct' as 'that which refers to an essential characteristic of N1+N2', if I read you correctly. Very brave; few would accept 'football' in 'football manager' to be indeterminate as to PoS without context. Have you references backing up your views? Would you say 'blue' in 'blue cheese' could sometimes be an adjunct rather than an adjective? What about 'whole' in 'he ate a whole pie'?

Comment: Please be aware that the downvote is not mine. This is food for thought; I'm convinced that, like the 'adverb' 'class', the 'adjective' 'class' will be overhauled one day. _former_? _mere_? _fake_? // I'm struggling with 'water clock' which seems to use 'water' as an adjunct until someone puts a candle and an alarm clock next to it – while it remains at all times a clepsydra.

Comment: No downvote from me either. But you need to be aware that the choice is between being a Modifier/Adjunct which you term an adjective and being a Compliment. A Compliment if you like is the opposite of an Adjunct/Modifier.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I appreciate the openness of the discussion on this notably tricky ground. I've edited my answer to offer a couple of references from the shelves of my home "office." There may be some better material back at the shop for me to look at in the coming week.  I have to add that my perspective is shaded by decades of trying to help American adolescents deal with the difference between a game boy and a Game Boy (if that even means anything any more). The discussion becomes even harder when we start quibbling over whose textbook's terminology is right. (And God help the agnostics.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - As to the cheese: yes, I would call the 'bleu' in 'bleu cheese" an adjunct, not an adjective, and not merely because for reasons known only to Julia Child we spell it in French. And while I'd love to come up with a clearer argument covering the whole, your *whole pie* will be a noun modified by an adjective - even if made with minced and sugared Wholes.  This whole discussion needs a few thousand fewer miles and a whole lot more ale.

Comment: So what is the role of "pin" in "doing a pin dance"?

Answer (score 2):

According to Herbst 2010: English Linguistics. A coursebook for Students of English, there are different models by different authors concerning determinative compounds. 'Football manager' is a determinative compound, because the first word defines the second one further.

Herbst himself gives 'killer shark' as an example, 'killer' being a complement, because it defines the subject, 'shark', further. So, in this case, 'football' would be a *complement*, 'manager' the subject.

According to Plag, Braun, Lappe and Schramm 2007: Introduction to English Linguistics, 'football' would be the *modifier*, and 'manager' the *head*.

Another model for the analysis of compounds is by Kastovsky. He distinguishes between determinant and determinantum (Kastovsky 2007: Vocabulary; Kastovsky 1982: Semantics and vocabulary) . When following this model, 'football' would be regarded as *determinant*, 'manager' as *determinantum*.

Comment: Football manager is not a determinative compound, because the *football* element is giving only extra information (AKA adjunct) rather than modifying the attributes of *manager*. The common distinction is *footstool* (http://www.odlt.org/ballast/determinative_compound.html), which is a stool for feet, not a stool with the attributes of a foot. Another common example is *office manager* who is the manager of an office, not a manager with the attributes of an office (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound). In the same way, a *football manager* lacks the attributes of a football.

Comment: @RoaringFish Hmm ... Attributive modifiers are adjuncts by definition (of the words 'adjunct' and 'modifier').

Comment: @Araucaria ~ yes, modifier is pretty much synonymous with adjunct or attribute, but so what? Whatever you call it, it is still very distinct from a complement or an argument. In simple terms, a modifier/adjunct/attribute is optional (as in *he is a (football) manager*) while a complement is indispensible, as in *her face became (white)*.

Comment: @RoaringFish But in *I smoke* there is no Object. In *I smoke cigarettes* there is an Object. So the Complement doesn't seem to be obligatory there ..., no?

Comment: @Araucaria ~ you confusing obeject with complement. In *I smoke cigarettes* there is no complement. Only a subject, a verb, and an object.

Answer (score 1):

Complement is a very vague term, with at least three meanings.

It can be predicative an assign a property to a subject or object, as in *David is angry*, where *angry* is being assigned to *David*. It can be the object argement of a verb, as in *David washed the car* where *the car* is the compelement of *washed*. In the broadest possible sense, it is somethng that 'completes', as in *with the cat* where *the cat* is needed to make *with* make sense.

Note that none of these apply to *football manager*, so by any argument *football* is not a complement of *manager*.

As the *football* element is optional because *he is a manager* works perfectly, the *football* element is a an [noun adjunct](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) by definition, but can also be called an attributive noun. The two terms are pretty much synonymous.

*"a noun adjunct or attributive noun or noun (pre)modifier is an optional noun that modifies another noun; it is a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase. For example, in the phrase "chicken soup" the noun adjunct "chicken" modifies the noun "soup".*

Comment: Please be aware that the downvote is not mine. Though the (possibly fourth) usage of 'complement' is not really addressed.

Comment: Any source for the uncoventional definitions of 'Complement'?

Comment: Sure. As a subject/object predicate here: http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAComplement.htm  As a verb argument here: http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Complement  Broad 'completion' here: http://www.odlt.org/ballast/determinative_compound.html  There is nothing unconventional about any of this. It is really quite standard - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics). None of these apply to *football manager* because whatever *football* is, it is definitely not a complement, nor a determinative compound.

Comment: @RoaringFish There certainly is, because of course *all* grammars count those things as Complements. The problem with your unconventional take is that it *only* counts those things as Complements. However, many other things are Complements too that are not arguments of a verb. For example the noun phrases which occur after prepositions, the content clauses that occur after nouns such as *idea* --> *The idea [that God exists]*, for example.There are gazillions more You can't make an argument that an animal isn't a mammal because dogs and cats are mammals and this animal isn't a dog or a cat.

Comment: @Auracaria ~ yes, by some definitions, some things that are not verb arguments are considered complements. I gave two definitions saying exactly that. Your example is covered by the broad definition, and hence proves nothing. What is 'unconventional' about thinking that only things that match the accepted definition of complements, are complements? Would you say that I was being inconventional if I said *happily* didn't fit the definition of a noun? If you are going to say that *football* is a complement of *manager*, then provide a definition of complement that supports your assertion.

Comment: So, what is "yellow" in "David is yellow"?

Answer (score 1):

"Football manager" is a compound noun and neither adjective  nor modifier nor complement are  adequate terms to describe a noun as element of a compound noun. English grammar has failed up to now to come up with an unambiguous term for a special subelement in word formation.

Word formation is a sector of its own. It has nothing to with word classes (adjective), nor word groups ( modifier), nor sentence part ( complement).
Traditional grammar has no terms for the various types of word formation because normal grammar does not cover the sector of word formation.

Added:

Somewhere I found the term "noun as combining form". I think combining noun would be an appropriate term when it is only used for describing the first noun of compound nouns of the type noun+noun.

Comment: Yet another view. I'm trying to think of a tight but not compound coupling of N + N form; I've given a reference to an analysis employing a gradience   (free association ... loose collocation ... strong collocation ... open compound) elswhere