# How reconnaissance is a noun but not an adjective?

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives

According to [Longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/reconnaissance), reconnaissance is a noun. However, in the provided examples I feel it has a role for describing another name.

> reconnaissance aircraft
>   a reconnaissance mission

Could someone explain how it is still a noun in such examples?

Comment: Hello, welcome to ELU. Can you elaborate what you mean when you say: *has a role for describing another name*.

Comment: @Gary, I mean it describes another name. Therefore, it must be an adjective. `reconnaissance aircraft` to me looks like saying a `blue aircraft`.

Comment: Ah i see, when a noun modifiers another it doesn't become an adjective. This is a noun adjunct. I have already answered this somewhere. I'll try to find the reference.

Comment: As Jim pointed out this is also answered in the question he has linked. If you have any question that isn't answered in there, feel free to edit your question, and reference the question Jim linked.In the meantime this question will likely be closed soon, because there are answers examining this exact category of question in the above link. -- also this link should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

Comment: @Gary, Thanks a lot. How to distinguish a noun adjunct from adjective? I mean how I can prove reconnaissance is a noun here?

Comment: @Stephen you're welcome Stephen, please see the first answer to this question: it explains the difference: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective

Comment: @Stephen An adjective cannot be a noun; an attributive noun can. Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments.

One big difference between attributive nouns and adjectives is that while an adjective is predicative, i.e., a `blue aircraft` is blue and is an aircraft, a `reconnaissance aircraft` is not reconnaissance, but rather it is an aircraft.

[Reference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/#answer-87611)