# Is there any adjectival form of "Audit"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives

I just made the mistake of using "Auditory" in the context of auditing. For example:

"We need to include that information, for *auditory* purposes."

After I sent my e-mail, I was embarrassed to find out that "auditory" refers to hearing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81961/discussion-on-question-by-mrmusaddict-is-there-an-adjective-form-of-audit).

Comment: It should be noted that the derivation of "audit" is from the Latin for "to hear", so "auditory" is not technically incorrect (though it would certainly confuse many).

Comment: Just use *audit*. For audit purposes. On a side note, I'm not sure that the comma is justified. And the hyphen in *email* certainly isn't.

Answer (score 1):

### Auditing

As a Native North American English speaker I would say, "We need to include that information, for auditing purposes."

[Source](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm) http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm

[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) -https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle

[Source](https://www.englishgrammar.org/participles/) - https://www.englishgrammar.org/participles/

[Source](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm) - https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm

"Auditing" in this case is used as a present participle. "Audited" can be used as the past participle.

For example, "Our data is stored in audited databases." And, "E & Y reviewed the auditing logs."

In my experience this usage is common in the Eastern United States.

Comment: That's a noun, not an adjective! Our purposes are more auditing than yours? Or are yours very auditing? Doesn't smell like an adjective to me: it's a noun. Not that he needs an adjective.

Comment: @tchrist However if I say "Do you require that for medical or auditing purposes?", is it the case that "medical" qualifies as an adjective, but "auditing" doesn't?

Comment: @tchrist I think it is technically a participle, which I believe can be used as an adjective.  http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm

Comment: I’m sorry, but your reference is wrong. To say that “participles” can be part of multiword verbs **or be** nouns **or be** adjectives is using that word in a highly nonstandard way that runs counter to modern analysis, where by “modern” I mean anything within living memory of anyone alive today. That’s just saying that a participle is any *-ing* word deriving from the base form of a verb. That’s a morphological criterion, not one that describes a word’s part of speech the way verb, noun, adjective and all do. It’s no adjective because it doesn’t let you do adjective things to it, (*continued*)

Comment: (...) and it lets you do things to it that you can only to do nouns. It's not grammatical to say the purposes are auditing. But you can use the adjective *intensive* to modify *auditing*: “Intensive auditing is our business” shows that that’s a noun there, and should also do so saying “This is for intensive auditing purposes” meaning for purposes of intensive auditing. This is a noun–noun compound, like in a *living wage*  being a wage **for** living. This is a purpose **for** auditing, so it has to be a noun. Notice also how you can have *very intensive* but not *very auditing*.

Comment: One last demo that this is not an adjective here:  flipping the first two words, both putative adjectives by your account, in *“intensive auditing purposes”*, produces *“auditing intensive purposes”* which means something completely different grammatically. It parses differently. Changing *“great green dragon”* into *“green great dragon”* may sound funny, but it doesn’t require a radical reassignment of parts of speech the way the other does. Hence, the first is not a pair of adjectives.

Comment: Check this post [Is this noun used as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective). Nice explanation on noun adjunct :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not recommending the phrasing when I say 'auditorial' works in your example sentence:

> We need to include that information, for *auditorial* purposes.

I'm sure there are better ways to put it, depending on context and intention. For example:

1. We need to audit that information.
2. That information must be included for the audit.
3. Etc.

From [*OED*](http://oed.com):

> **auditorial**, *adj.*
>   ...
>   **2.** Of or pertaining to auditors of accounts; *connected with an audit*.

In your example, the purposes are *connected with an audit*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91184/discussion-between-lordology-and-jel).

Comment: I have [raised this on Meta.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12082/commonly-available-reference-issue)

Comment: 'auditorial' may well be literally correct, but it really sounds like you're talking about hearing. I'd suggest the noun attribute, as in 'audit purposes'.

Comment: @Mitch, I think the caveat is well enough embedded in the answer. To me, "audit purposes" sounds redundant, flabby businessese: an audit has purpose all on its own. Hence, my examples of better ways to put it.