# What part of speech would this word be?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What part of speech are the following highlighted words?

- the **bank** card
- the **Lloyds** card

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this noun used as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective)

Comment: They are noun phrases; and the bold-faced ones function as adjs.

Comment: Note that by making the edits you did, you unintentionally vandalized your own question, making it impossible to answer. I have reinstated the highlighted words you were referencing but had deleted.

Comment: @RamPillai I wouldn't go along with what you say. Adjective is not a function but a part of speech. The nouns in bold are attributive (or pre-head) modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Nouns can modify nouns in English. I would say they are nouns functioning as modifiers which typically are taken care of by adjectives.

Comment: They are commonly referred to as *attributive nouns* or *noun adjuncts*.