# Why is "brick" in "a brick house" a noun, whereas "plastic" in "a plastic bucket" is an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

Taking these classifications from Oxford's Lexico:

- [plastic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/plastic)
- [brick](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brick)

Comment: I'm not seeing the term 'brick house' on the page you link. Can you clarify your assumptions?

Comment: @Spagirl I'm not sure that matters. It does have "brick saw" which is the same type of phrase.

Comment: @Laurel It does actually matter. We shouldn't have to go to another site to fully understand a question. The relevant parts of the definition should be excerpted, and the author should explain whether the issue is that there is no definition for "brick" as an adjective, or whether the issue arose from the fact there was an example sentence under the definition of brick as a noun. Not because we can't figure it out, but because that information makes the question more discoverable.

Comment: ["Plastic" is also a noun.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMtLdE5Zq-8)

Comment: @Laurel, genuine question, *is it* the same kind of phrase? in 'brick house' brick describes what the house is made of, but in 'brick saw' it tells us what it is made *for*.

Comment: @ColleenV The issue is that there is no definition for "brick" as an adjective.

Comment: @philipxy: A noun which is mostly used to describe materials that are, ironically, not plastic(adj).

Comment: On a related note, compare & contrast "air pump", "air rifle", and "air guitar".

Comment: @Spagirl Grammatically, they are both "brick + noun" (unlike the other examples using brick on its own). What I'm saying is, does it matter in the sense that the question needs to be clarified? Any perceived difference you see seems like something that should be addressed in an answer. The question is perfectly clear to me.

Comment: I can show you a "brick", but I cannot show you a "plastic". In this usage, "brick" is an enumerable object, "plastic" is not.

Comment: You get what you deserve when you try to look up grammatical information in a dictionary!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This may have been addressed here before, but the overall answer is 'there is no consensus as to when certain words should be considered attributive nouns, and when they should be considered to have converted fully to adjectives', obviously in these instances used prenominally. 'Steel bridge' is a famous case in issue.

Nordquist at [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012) discusses this issue:

> - "Webster's New International Dictionary . . . does not call every noun capable of attributive use an adjective but some like *cash*,
>   *land*, *mind* etc. are labeled 'n(oun) often attrib(utive).'
>
> However, the distinction between words that are 'n often attrib' and
> words that *are* 'adj' is not precise, as the editors themselves claim
> . . .. Moreover, even one author may provide different explanations
> for similar cases. Gove (1964:165), for example, considers the word
> *zero* in *zero modification* an adjective in the light of its attributive and predicative uses, despite the fact that it neither
> inflects for degree nor admits adverbial modification. However,
> surprisingly enough, for *macaroni salad*, apparently similar to the
> *zero modification* example, he argues that there appears to be a 'strong feeling' against *macaroni* as an adjective."

The usual tests for adjectives include gradability and intensifiability, but just as 'steel' in 'steel bridge' fails this

- *a steeler bridge
- *a very steel bridge

so does the obvious classifying adjective 'nuclear'

- *a more nuclear reactor
- *a very nuclear explosion.

For particular classifications, only asking say the compilers why they chose contrasting POSs for apparently identical usages will begin to resolve the question.

But checking in the usual respectable dictionaries (in particular AHD, Collins, RHK Webster's, Lexico, M-W, CD, Longmans, Macmillan) for POS assignment of 'plastic', all concur that full conversion to the adjective has now occurred, even for the basic 'made of plastic' ('plastic spoon') sense.

But for 'brick', [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brick) has 'noun, often attributive', [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brick) calls the usage 'noun as modifier', and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brick) and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/brick_1) also list 'a brick wall' under [noun].  [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brick) is, I'd say, unclear (though gives 'red-brick houses' under [noun]). [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=brick) and [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/brick) seem not to address the issue, but do not list *adjective* usages. **However** [RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/brick) classifies 'brick' in the senses 'made of, constructed with, or resembling bricks' [adjective].

Comment: Plastic is also a "true" adjective in its other senses: "that moulds" e.g. *plastic art* and "generating ideas; creative" e.g., *a plastic imagination* (OED)

Comment: If so, it's converted from the original noun usage, and as stated above linguists disagree on when certain words / senses can be said to have made this breakthrough.

Comment: Linguists may disagree, but [The Academy](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) decides.

Comment: "Very nuclear" sounds somewhat less unacceptable than "very steel".

Comment: There's no doubt that in the NP "a brick wall", "brick" is a nominal consisting of a noun; likewise "cotton" in "a cotton shirt". And _probably_ "plastic" too, as in "a plastic pipe".

Comment: Thank you for another one of your positive contributions. I think this answer nails the issue: it reflects on the issue at a higher level, instead of assuming simple criteria or copying judgements from works of reference, as some linguists do. Linguistics is often 'soft' and not an exact, experimental science.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to make that less opinionative, @Lawrence.

Comment: I gave this +1 despite the missed opportunity to write “nuclearer” while still saying something intelligent.

Comment: Test ❶: Can you modify *brick* or *plastic* with an adjective that applies only to them not to some noun that follows them? When you have a fake brick house, the house is real but the brick is fake, so the brick can only be an attributive noun there.  Test ❷: Can you use these prospective adjectives predicatively, not just attributively? If those are predicate adjectives, then *the bridge is steel, the spoon is plastic, the house is brick* “should” (necessary ʙᴜᴛ ɴᴏᴛ sufficient) all read ok. Yet *the bridge is stainless steel, the spoon is crumbling plastic, the house is fake brick* disproves.

Comment: [@EdwinAshworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586534/why-is-brick-in-a-brick-house-a-noun-whereas-plastic-in-a-plastic-bucket/586537?noredirect=1#comment1469016_586537) Recent years have seen various non-standard phrasings such as adding "not" to the end of a positive statement to negate it theatrically. "Very [noun phrase]" is one of them, used in a context such as "This is very you". Not all noun phrases work well with this construction, but _nuclear_ seems to work better than _steel_. "Very Michigan" and "very '60s" sound better than "very bicycle" or "very wall".

Comment: @Lawrence interesting observation. I wonder what causes this distinction between Michigan and bicycle. Is it the ease of identifying the stereotypical attribute?

Comment: IMO, the reason "very you", "very 60s" and "very Michigan" sound fine is because "you", "the 60s" and "Michigan" are identities - there is only one you, one decade called the 60s, and one Michigan - whereas there are many bicycles with different identities. Saying something is "very Michigan" means it is somehow specific to Michigan (or styles associated with Michigan) as opposed to other cities (i.e. other things of the same type as Michigan). In contrast, "very bicycle" doesn't sound right, because a quality cannot be specific to "bicycle" as opposed to... other bicycles?

Comment: @kaya3 I was halfway through a disagreeing comment about "very nuclear" when I realized that nuclear is always an adjective. You can't go to the store and say "Please give me five nuclears."

Comment: @Lawrence Like my previous comment, I don't think "nuclear" is *ever* a noun.

Comment: @Ross Presser Sorry; there I've got to disagree. In power generation usages, 'We will make use of gas, oil and nuclear' shows a local conversion. But in 'a coal-fired / nuclear  power station', the adjective persists.

Comment: @RossPresser Good point. The noun is _nucleus_.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nuclear): '**nuclear** ... ... ... [noun] [informal] _nuclear energy_:
'switching to nuclear as a power source.' ' _Ditto_ [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nuclear). _Ditto_, without the 'informal' caveat, Wiktionary.

Comment: OK, so it's transitioning as of this generation I guess. I doubt it would be considered correct in the 1940s.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!

Answer (score 10):

The use of the word "plastic" as an adjective, and even the phrase "plastic surgery", substantially predate the invention of the materials which are commonly called "plastics", and the use of "plastic" as a noun referring to such materials.  It's perhaps somewhat ironic that some of the first materials which were called "plastics", such as Bakelite (invented in 1907), weren't really very plastic at all once formed but were in fact quite brittle, unlike plasticine which was invented twenty years earlier.

I think the term "plastic" should properly be thought of as being an attributive noun when it is referring to a brittle synthetic resin, and an adjective when describing a characteristic of a material (e.g. "heat the object until it starts to become plastic") or process (e.g. "plastic deformation", "plastic surgery", etc.).  While the primary usage of the word would be as an attributive noun, it can also be used as an adjective in a way that "brick" cannot.

Incidentally, a further distinction between meanings can be illustrated by considering the effect of the adverb "more".  Saying something is "more plastic" would be more flexible but less elastic.  To describe an object which is not flexible as being more like the synthetic resins which are commonly called "plastics", one would instead say "more plasticky".

Comment: A "hard plastic spoon" makes sense as a spoon made of hard plastic. A "hard, plastic spoon" would be correct if "plastic" were being used as an adjective, but to me this usage suggests the earlier usages of "plastic" meaning more or less "soft". It would of course be difficult to make a hard spoon out of plastic that was not hard.

Comment: 'X should be considered a noun (etc) when ...' becomes an untenable stance when conversion occurs. 'Funnest' and increasingly 'funner' are now considered acceptable, obviously the superlative and comparative of a new adjective. English is plastic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I was somewhat bummed, though, when I was playing Scrabble against the computer and it wouldn't accept "SLANTIER" as a valid word, even though it does accept e.g. "brownier" as a comparative form of "browny", an adjective meaning "somewhat brown".  On the flip side, the term "via" is often used in electronics-related technical writing as a noun meaning "plated through-hole connection", with the plural form "vias", but OSPD doesn't recognize that usage either.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that OSPD is seen as a recognised authority on ELU. But arguments start when AHD say calls a usage that of a 'noun' while R H K Webster's considers it now to be that of an 'adjective'. We have to look for papers/articles on the subject, for instance [the views of Denison in _Pastor Gómez' Nominal Modifiers in Noun Phrase Structure: Evidence from Contemporary English_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: My intended point was that the question of what prefix-stem-suffix combinations are "words" is rather vague, and offer examples where an entity that tries to reasonably judge such things may not make such distinctions the same way as a typical reader.

Comment: Dictionaries (even Grand Ol' OED) are often considered really inadequate (contrast respected grammars such as CGEL) when it comes to attributing POS correctly. Though most have conceded the existence of determiners/determinatives in the last decade or so. And as the article I linked to indicates, the real experts in these areas don't always agree. // As regards wordness, OED has about 2/3 m, while famously the 1m mark was claimed to have been reached a few years ago. Wiktionary has the greatest number, though some think it's not adequately vetted.

Answer (score 8):

It's a brick house because it is made out of bricks, which are objects. It is not saying the house is 'bricky'.

Consider the difference between 'a wooden house' and 'a log house'. Logs are objects. Wood is not.

Comment: A paper airplane is made out of paper. But Lexico (https://www.lexico.com/definition/paper) does not give any definition of "paper" as an adjective.

Comment: @peisander: I'm a bit surprised that "paper" wouldn't have a definition as an adjective describing a lack of substantial and reliable value, as used in such expressions as "paper tiger" or "paper promises".  Note that the phrase "paper promise" doesn't merely describe promise which is expressed in paper form (i.e. a contract), but rather a promise which is likely to be breached and is unlikely to be usefully enforceable.  Otherwise, I think there's a presumption that if someone sees a reference to e.g. a "macguffium statue", and the only definition for "macguffium" describes a material...

Comment: ...they would interpret the word as an attributive adjective meaning "made of macguffium", even if the dictionary contains no such definition.  If a dictionary had some other definition of the word as an adjective, then it should *also* explicitly include a "made of macguffium" definition, but otherwise it would be pointless to try to guess whether anyone had used the name of each possible material as an attributive adjective.

Answer (score 0):

"Brick house" and "plastic bucket" differ through context, not gramattic form. If one is made of, and the other is meant for containing, they're different.

For example, "a wooden shed" is built of and a "wood shed" is built to contain wood.

Moving away, "a brick bucket" might mean a smaller bucket containing small bricks in a toy-box, or a bigger one containing bigger bricks on a building site, but never a bucket made of brick.